# Add a separate filter for "Not about programming or software development" in the close vote queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, filtering

The most problematic, the least suitable questions, that need to be dealt with fast, are the ones that fall into the "Not about programming or software development" category.

Those cannot get fixed as they are completely off-topic for the site. If they are answered, they still don't belong here.

At the moment, the filter that will show such unfixable off-topic questions is "Not suitable for this site" which also includes programming questions that lack debugging details and typo questions. This kind of filtering makes it impossible to focus only on closing completely off-topic questions in the Close vote queue.

Can we please have an additional filter option that will cover only "Not programming related questions"?

---

If there is a limit in the number of filtering options, then the filtering options could be easily reorganized where "Needs details or clarity" would cover all other close reasons from the current "Not suitable for this site" filter, except from "Non programming related questions".

That way, "Not suitable for this site" would only show questions that are asked on the wrong site and cannot be fixed at all.

Comment: Related (old) FR on MSE [Allow us to additionally filter off-topic close reasons in the Close Vote Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191540/1099857) which asks for all community specific reasons to be filter options.

Comment: Also related here on MSO [Can we have a "recommendation and off-site resource" filter for the Close Review Queue?](/q/267691/15497888)

Comment: Honestly, shouldn't "homework question" come in as a close second? Seems like there are some fairly common close vote reasons that are more tacitly conveyed through other options on the "does not belong in this community" tab. I feel like this would be to the benefit of both the community and new members.

Comment: Another suggestions perhaps could be, for example, "question contains code as image rather than markdown"

Comment: @Ethan Homework is not off-topic by itself. In contrast, "Not about programming or software development" is a literal close reason.

Comment: @Ethan There are no close-vote reasons that are "tacitly conveyed through other options". The name for such close votes is ***incorrect***. If none of the close-vote reasons in the list fits, then the question shouldn't be closed. As has already been noted, homework questions are not off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for Stack Overflow. That's why there's no close reason for them. Avoid making up new close-vote reasons. If you're bothered by a question but can't find a suitable close-vote reason, you can downvote it.

Comment: That is not how it works. Certain issues *lead to* specific close reasons being applicable. For example, if a "question contains code as image rather than markdown" that means it has no [MRE] and thus lacks debugging details - provided it actually is a debugging question about that code. If one were to, say, ask why code is rendered a specific way by some tool then an image is appropriate.

Comment: My comments refer to the fact that, yes, while all of these close votes ARE contained within the current framework, not adding a layer of specificity here is only to the detriment of the new users. They see their questions closed, but may not fully understand what specifically to improve or what their question was lacking. I guess it was more a comment on how we can make feedback to new users more clear so that they are well equip to ask better/more detailed questions in the future if they are faced with an initial close vote.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi my only concern is that "lacks debugging details" may or may not signal to the new users that they need to format their code as a non-image. This is obvious to us but may not be to new users.

Comment: People asking for new moderation features to be added to Stack Overflow in 2022 have me like https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/laughing-tom-cruise given how little Stack Exchange Inc. cares.

Comment: I think voting to close a homework question as "Needs focus" (the close reason I use when the question is just the homework assignment description, with no code) gives the user more information than a "homework" close reason.

Comment: Even if none of the reasons fit, you can write your own @Ethan. It's funny how the comment that showed that was deleted, yet the comment that says that "only the listed reasons are valid" stays, which is patently false.

Comment: @IanKemp sad but true. Feature requests in general, I would say. The only feature requests that are ever implemented now are [those that are so small they might as well be called a bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419236/some-comments-dont-get-deleted-automatically-immediately-on-flagging).

Answer (score -20):

I have a filter that mostly catches those kinds of questions. It's a combination of selecting community-specific and OS tags.

At 1.2 million strong only for the three main OSes in the world, that feels like a crap-shot. I still believe that we should just remove tags that give the impression that off-topic questions are allowed on the site, since that would cut the most common argument in the bud to ask off-topic questions: if you don't allow questions about X, why do you have a tag for X?

Comment: There is large number of tags besides OS, that host off topic questions. And if you filter by OS you will still have plenty of on topic questions in there. Also in more obscure tags questions can easily fly under the radar.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar on the close queue I doubt you would have "plenty of on topic questions". I basically burn just with [debian]. But that's besides the point of my answer. My point is that we are treating the symptoms instead of the disease: get rid of off topic tags.

Comment: Those tags you call off-topic are actually on-topic. It is not the problem in tags (there may be exceptions), but in off topic questions that fall under the same tag. There are plenty of on topic Android, iOS, Windows, Linux... questions. If you want to treat the real cause, then this goes beyond tags and the root cause is lack of guidance for new users. Point of my feature request is simple: I want filter that will simply filter questions that fall in "Not about programming" category regardless of a tag. If you want to remove "off topic" tags, then you should post new feature request.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar A question which only tag that applies is the "windows" tag will never be on topic. Keeping a tag that can't work an on topic question as the only tag is pure madness. Search for it. I will be waiting.

Comment: "How do I program on Windows" would be on topic and only have that tag, though it would be an invalid question for a host of other reasons

Comment: What are you talking about? How is question having single tag relevant to at all? If I filter questions in CV queue and specify additional filtering tags, that filtering will show questions where one of the tags is the one specified, not questions where this is the one and only tag. Besides, most non programing related questions have multiple tags.

Comment: Or are you saying that we don't need OS tags at all because other "on topic" tags will suffice? If this is the case, I have to strongly disagree because we need OS tag to cover interacting with various OS APIs.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar "to cover interacting with various OS APIs" come on, we already have tags for those api's. We don't need a generic "here's a bag of api's, figure it out". Also, considering that people tend to specialize on some of them, not all, having specific tags is more effective way to communicate that.

Comment: BTW, and in case is not clear @DalijaPrasnikar , I'm not against having a specific filter, I just think that there are more effective ways to actually make the job manageable. We need to reduce the number of off topic questions, removing the impression that those questions are on topic is the first step.

Comment: @Braiam No we generally don't have tags for OS APIs. Those APIs are covered with OS tags. Exception might be Windows where we have WinAPI, but that is also rather specific API that does not cover everything Windows related.