# Why can't I upload an image anymore?

Tags: bug, status-completed, image-upload, imgur

I'm working on [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77905378/4279155), but when I try to add a screenshot, I get following error message:

> Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

In case you say: "Can't you show the actual dialogbox instead of just the error message?", then you might imagine why I'm not doing that :-)

I'm working with Windows 10, Google Chrome, incognito.

Comment: Also on MSE: [Can't upload images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396425)

Comment: @VLAZ: thanks, I had no idea it was a general StackExchange problem.

Comment: This is by design to resolve [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) once and for all ....

Comment: @rene: I don't want to post an image of code data, or error messages. I want to add an explanatory screenshot to the mentioned post.

Comment: @rene: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Dominique screenshots of code submitted as part of Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @rene are you suggesting images of code are being recognized and rejected? You might want to re-read your comments because they're a little difficult to follow.

Comment: @Cerbrus no, all images are rejected. No more images, no more problems.

Comment: Now they need to do the same with regex, and we'll be _mostly_ problem-free.

Comment: @yivi small steps, small steps, but yes please.

Comment: @Dominique the opinion was stated as a joke.

Comment: @VLAZ: I'm sorry. I'm so used seeing comments with smileys that, when a comment does not contain a smiley, I tend to take it serious. My mistake :-)

Comment: The comment contains a special smiley spelled "rene"

Comment: all sizes of images are rejected.

Comment: Can’t you just supply a table with colour values, in the markdown? 1000 columns, 600 rows?

Comment: Mo images, mo problems.

Comment: Related: *[No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it/385424#385424)*. [Stack Overflow is *** ***not*** *** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This issue has been resolved - quoting myself [from Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396425/cant-upload-images):

> Thank you for making this post. We diagnosed the issue with Imgur uploads and reached out to Imgur for support. They responded quickly, investigated, and resolved the issue.
>
> We should now have full function for image uploads network-wide. Please feel free to point any per-site Meta questions on the topic to this answer.

Comment: Just a question: this happened once and I've written a post, tagged "bug" for this. It has been solved, so the tag "status-completed" has been added. Now imagine the situation happens again in future: do I need to write a new request (keep in mind that no two posts can have the same title), or do I reopen this question (keep in mind that multiple reopen votes are needed for this)?

Comment: @Dominique I'd recommend writing a new question. If the exact same issue recurs (and it really is exactly the same), just link back to this post