# Do we allow religious invocations in questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102474/set-enable-qlineedit-by-edit-another-qlineedit) (now deleted, so visible to 10K users only). The question began thus:

> In The Name Of God. I want enable other Qlineedit in my program with write "abc" in another Qlineedit in my program.

Do religious invocations stay, or should they be edited out?

I ask because editing such out seems to my out-of-whack PC sense to be slightly on the sensitive side. I really don't like to offend anyone for non-meritorious reasons (as in: I'll call you out on bad code, not on your religion). If the consensus is to prune such, then prune I'll do.

Comment: Does the question become less clear if you remove it? If not, then it is noise and has no place in a post.

Comment: I've removed it from the post; it is no more useful than *Thanks in advance* and *Hello Stack Overflow!*.

Comment: It is essentially a salutation, and thus should follow the existing policy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I would especially deny religious statements in _"The name of Beelzebub"_ Bub. You have problems man (eyerolling), noise is noise :-P ...

Comment: Religious invocations are noise...unless they're related to the second coming of [Tony the pony](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/176646).

Comment: Looking down the edits it seems the phrase in question has already been edited out once before and replaced by the OP. If he's still watching the question we may expect to see it return.

Comment: It almost makes the question read like the start of a Nigerian scam. Therefore it should be removed with extreme prejudice. Everyone knows there are plenty of demons but no deities in the programming world.

Comment: Only if it's `Hello World` and you're a follower of Gaia.

Comment: In the name of Sponge Bob the great and all powerful one. No, get rid of it.  Questions asked here are for real persons to answer, not for imaginary help.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with Yvette that this is a duplicate of the said questions. For example, the matter being discussed here is quite offset from the single official reference given in the single answer posted to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351588/can-we-have-an-official-statement-regarding-greetings-salutations-etc-please

Answer (score 46):

No. It's not material to the question so it's noise and noise should be removed.

Comment: I respectfully disagree it is noise. For example, "God bless" in the answer; If God indeed blesses a reader who is trying to implement an answer (or even before such time - in helping one find the answer), then one may actually be aided infinitely by such invocation.

Comment: @Roel: the difficulty with your defence is that it requires a belief in god in order to assess its veracity. You cannot require atheists or agnostics to believe that supernatural blessings might benefit them - they do not believe that, and will not believe it in order to hear your argument.

Comment: I did not state a defence. My comment is 1) a belief, 2) an argument. As far as my comment was my belief (i.e. God exists), that is my own. As for my argument, it stands by it's own and does not require a belief in God. Allow me to explain; any other answer on SO (i.e. without "God bless" in it) which *may* help (i.e. where it is not clear whether it will help or not) will be left as-is, until such time as greater clarity is achieved. By the same token, whether God exists or not, if my answer includes "God bless" and that *may* help if God indeed exists, then I submit it should be left alone.

Comment: @halfer  the difficulty with your defence is that it requires a belief in absolute nothingness and a totally random universe functioning all on its own, which obviously makes no sense at all, in order to assess its veracity. You cannot require actual people or agnostics to believe that supernatural randomness might benefit them - they do not believe that, and will not believe it in order to hear your argument.

Comment: @bluejayke: if you need to make a theistic point in order to further your side of the debate, you've already conceded the wider argument being made: theistic discussion doesn't belong on the site. That remains the case, several years after this meta-question was posted.

Comment: @halfer I dont recall mentioning the term "theist" I identify as a complete atheist, I am rather offended that you would associate me with theistic thoughts at all, nothing about my comment even suggested anything in the slightest about "theist"

Comment: OK, @bluejayke. You seemed to be making an argument based on Intelligent Design (particularly that you thought that a belief in a random universe was nonsensical, which I thought would imply you believe there is a Higher Power behind it). If you say you were not making that argument, then alright. I am not sure what we are talking about then, given that we are probably in agreement - it seems that your first comment here copy+pastes something I've said already!

Comment: (I advocate making a real effort to not take offence on the internet - taking offense is a widespread Western cultural phenomenon at the moment, and we should all try to resist that if we can. The primary judgement to make on that theme is whether I intended to cause you any offence, and I can assure you that I did not).

Comment: @halfer OK good to know you didnt intend it, I'm not talking about (specifically) this "intelligent design" concept, I'm talking about a Creator that constatnly runs every detail of the world, even now, as opposed to the laws of nature just happening on their own

Answer (score -35):

I believe if any term used is truly provocative (hateful for example) they should be edited out.

But idioms such as "Thank God", oh "my God", and the likes do not need to be edited out, since they are very common and more importantly not identified as abusive or hurtful, offensive to anyone and if they do get edited and removed, that's when it truly becomes provocative at that moment.

When anything related to such sensitive subjects is to be decided upon, there need to be clear examples of that or personal interpretation can make everything worse.

Comment: Thanks for being willing to state your case here. I think the community will be in disagreement with it, since it will generally be thought of [as "fluff" material](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) in the same way as thanks, salutations, signatures and hope-you-can-helps.

Comment: @halfer: That makes it a completely different case! completely different! 
Although I do not see thanks or the likes as distractive but thats OK with me and there is no problem with that. 
However, in order for everything to work out perfectly, I firmly believe a comprehensive list of examples denoting each case for each category need to be available and used so any personal interpretation is avoided and more importantly they can be referenced.  
and by the way, this community has millions of users, and for your comment to be true, you need to get all of their votes

Comment: on the subject. This tiny fraction does not represent the whole community in anyway

Comment: The context for this answer is that Coderx7 would like to thank god for helping them with their answers on the main site. I have trimmed a couple of these out from self-answers, since I think they are not germane to the technical content, but Coderx7 would like to insist upon them, and will roll such edits back.

Comment: I have told you before, you have been trying to provoke me for the past two days now. Let me make it clear for you, If you or anyone else tries to edit my posts which do not have any issues, I will roll those changes back.
based on the community guideline concerning edits, the edits need to be substantial and make the post better. 
This does not apply to any of my posts. especially the one you are talking about. and I am not violating any rules that I know of.
You are deliberately trying to offend me. and therefore violating the very primitive rule of the community about bigotry. because

Comment: your intention is not as you claim, for making the post better! you are trying to impose your own belief system on me and harass me in that regard. in none of your edits, anything useful is added to the post that makes it better or adds to its usefulness, or pretty much any of the matters discussed in the edit guidelines.

Comment: As you know, we are in disagreement. As I have made clear, I am not interested in provoking you - just drawing your attention to the guidelines. It is good that you have put your case here though, so you can find out what other community members think.

Comment: As I have already said, a tiny fraction of the community(which is 0.000151% of the whole community!) does not in any way, represent the whole community. The only thing that I abide by is the rules. and I have not violated any so far. but you did! so I don't want to continue this aimless discussion with you. you know my opinion and know I won't be accepting anything that is not a rule. when something is a rule feel free to act upon it and if in doubt that I may not know it,refer me to the exact community guideline and rule to back your action.until then don't bother yourself and me anymore.

Comment: If you rollback edits that remove noise from questions, and anything about “god” is by definition noise on a programming Q+A site, you will be breaking the rules, and should expect to lose your editing privileges. This is a fight you will never win.

Comment: RE: "a tiny fraction of the community" - currently your answer here is on 18 downvotes and 0 upvotes. So of the people that have seen it and bothered to vote 100% of them disagree.

Comment: @Clive: This is getting ridiculous, bunch of users from UK trying to back up one of the pals, smoking the bad guy!! what can I say! seriously! 
let me make it clear for you as well. The discussion was not about noise! The comments are there and you can ask your pal about it. 
If anyone claims that he or she is editing a post of mine in order to remove noise, he or she must do it to the full extent. so that a guy like me cant say they started a childish game

Comment: to prove I don't know what! 
So to anyone who wants to "Improve" my posts(Martin), do it properly or I'll roll back because I firmly believe the intention was something else. 
When I see that, then there is nothing to nag about and all is fine .

Comment: I had no idea that whoever you're talking about is from the UK, I couldn't care less. It's actually rather arrogant that you assume people are disagreeing with you out of spite, and not simply because you're wrong. The only childish behaviour that could come of this is you rolling back edits that remove references to god, unless those references are somehow central to the issue at hand. If _you_ weren't trying to be provocative, you wouldn't even include those references now that you know in certain terms that they shouldn't be there

Comment: @Clive: if it wasn't for him telling me to go lobbying!!! for a simple matter like this, and then  out of 8 million users, and 100+ countries, couple of users from the UK suddenly show up and start to discuss this without reading what happened earlier, that's not my fault to think like that. 
I said I have no issue with removing noise, again that answer of mine had a lot of noise, to be honest, thank God and the likes aside. 
I told you that's not the case. What I see is someone told me to remove Thanks God, not because it is a noise! or he

Comment: considers it noise! or cares to remove the noise! but to force his interpretation of something or imposing his will. That I do not accept. 
I said it before and reiterate that, If you think that my post has noise, remove all of those noises, if you only remove the God part, and let the rest intact that has other meanings. it's as simple as that. 
That's, why I said whoever edited my post, needs to do it properly so no other intentions rather than fixing an issue and improving or helping the community is conveyed.

Comment: You did read your own answer, didn't you? _idioms such as "Thank God", oh "my God", and the likes do not need to be edited out, since they are very common and more importantly not identified as abusive or hurtful, offensive to anyone and if they do get edited and removed, that's when it truly becomes provocative_ Unsurprisingly, that's what people are taking you to task on, not new issues/dilutions you're raising in the comments. If you position has changed, and you now agree that those references should be removed, as part of a proper, full, edit, then update the answer to match

Comment: @Clive: This was asked about whether this was considered a religious invocation or not! 
and again I said it in the very first comment, that If you we look at it as a noise, I have no issue of removing it (alongside other noises ). but pay attention here, but ! if out of all the noises in the answer, someone picks out only the God part, that's a different story.

Comment: Again, that's not what your answer says. Seriously, read it again, then read the comments. You're arguing a completely different position in each.

Comment: @Clive: I just did! I don't see any contradiction between my comments. I'm saying I have not violated any rules, based on community guidelines. Anyone and everyone is welcomed to improve my posts by removing noises. However, it is strictly mentioned in the guidelines that the edits must be "substantial", they must "improve it" and it is mentioned what that means! So when someone out of all noises and irrelevant phrases, words, sentences, etc,  bothers himself to only remove the God part, it becomes provocative and questions his true intention. was it sincere, was it genuine,

Comment: or was it only to spread or impose one's belief or degrading the others? 
What I'm saying, is in order to prevent this, and you can already clearly see why all of the noises must be removed. and if someone proceeds to remove God! leaving the rest, there is no reason why I should not object. after all, we should be treated equally.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion.** If you want to make a counter-veiling argument, then do so in a new answer.

Comment: I don't see any difference between "Thank god" or "Thank you" or "Please help". All of them are just noise to the question and should be removed. Always ask yourself: "When I remove the sentence/phrase would that change the question or any answers to it?". If the answer is no, then remove it.

Comment: @BDL, that's right. The core of the discussion was that my answer had a lot of noises, to begin with, but the edits were only directed at removing the God part, not the rest. that ensued this discussion. I rolled back the changes that I thought weren't after noises but were actually to impose a specific mindset or belief, and to me looked as a derogatory remark. I said if anyone is after removing the noises, and improve the post, he must remove all of them and on top of that the edit must be substantial to being with.if this wasnt done, then their intentions is questionable.

Comment: The "must remove all of them" part is in my opinion only important for users without editing privilege. For everyone else: Whatever improves the post should be kept. Actually, if you know that your question contains a lot of noise, you should be the first one to remove it.

Comment: @BDL: That's correct, that actually doesn't mean that I deliberately add noises or I'm against removing them, the whole discussion is about only one post, and that is only a self-answered one, I usually try to not to deviate from the real problem and avoid adding any noise.you can have a look at my answers, to verify that. 
the thing is, this discussion got out of hand because that really wasn't about noise removal, and it started as a religious related issue and abiding by the rules or one's interpretation of rules/imposing one's will on the other etc.Anyway if you read the comments, you'll

Comment: know. I don't think this discussion needs to be any longer than it is already.

Comment: And stuff about religion is so gratingly off topic in a programming Q&A don't be surprised if people focus on that.

Comment: @martinSmith: I agree, I'm not surprised, becasue I'm also here becasue of that.

Comment: @BDL "Thank G-d" actually gives infinite powers to the one answering the question, thus making it the absolutely most essential thing of all reality, what could be more essential?