# Second opinion requested on user rolling back changes to remove religious material

Tags: discussion, edits, low-quality-posts

As well as answering the odd question on the main site, I am an active editor - I spend time trimming chat, fixing case, improving spelling and grammar, and so forth. In 99% of cases, my edits are accepted without quibble, and are understood by the author as helpful in making the post easier to read.

On rare occasions, I find that my edit has been rolled back, presumably because the OP believes their have "ownership" of their post in the way they would in a forum. Where a rollback is obviously wrong, I will generally flag for a moderator, who will generally agree with my edit and will restore it.

However, I have found one user who is putting "all the best" and "God bless" in a number of their lower-case and badly-punctuated posts, and they've reverted two of my edits ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36553286) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36513152)). [Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36366483/revisions) they've added remarks to the effect of "Jesus loves you :) I've been told not to say that on here BUT without Jesus my life ain't worth living" - thankfully that has been excised and has not yet made a re-appearance.

In each of the above rollbacks, my changes to fix case and apostrophes have also been removed. I reported this to a moderator, and received this response:

> Frankly, I don't think this is worth arguing over. If they're that adamant about leaving that little extra wording in there, it's not worth the fight.

Now, my OCD-inclined editing is happy to give way over two posts, but I am worried that we are sending the message that religious evangelism in posts is acceptable, and that rollbacks to restore it are free to delete improvements to case, spelling, apostrophes, etc.

**SUMMARY**:

I sometimes feel we're losing the battle over post quality - an eternal September of *"PLZ HALP ME!"* and *"URGENT!"* and now *"JESUS LOVES YOU"* - and that it matters whether or not keen editors can rely on moderators to (try to) uphold quality and readability standards.

Would the community and/or another moderator offer their opinion?

I will of course give way if that is the consensus.

**POST-DISCUSSION SUMMARY:**

Thanks to all who contributed to the discussion. I will try to reduce the number of edits that accidentally focus on one user, and will attempt to soften the sharp edges of my editing remarks, even where posters are editing in material they know to be discouraged.

In addition, I'll consider rare edit-war rollbacks as part of the editor's burden, and will sometimes just downvote rather than always flagging for a moderator.

**UPDATE APRIL 2016**

Despite my original flag being rejected, another moderator kindly restored my edits, and a polite note was issued to the user, asking if they could stick to reference quality writing.

Unfortunately since then [the same fluff material is being added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36653713), despite several people and moderators asking for some desistance. Given that I would be pushing my luck to flag this, I will instead try for a constructive dialogue in the comments.

**UPDATE JUNE 2016**

This user is [at it again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37968851/472495), even after a variety of community and moderator interventions. Note that I am not following him around - I have a variety of bookmarked trigger-phrase searches and he has come up on my radar again. Since I have expended my capital in editing posts from this user, and feel that flagging will probably be rejected, I will leave it here in case someone else from the community would like to edit.

I've noticed this post is related to [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295810/do-we-allow-religious-invocations-in-questions-answers).

Comment: Stuff like that is clearly considered as unrelated noise and should be edited out of course.

Comment: Speaking as the devil's lawyer (well, not quite in this case: is it still okay to ask for Blessings on [amongst others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+god+bless) jQuery and SimpleXML?

Comment: Well that is what demotivates me to even edit a post into shape, because sometimes OP will just roll it back and then you would have to put more effort into the post, which is not yours, just that it is a better post and that your effort isn't wasted.

Comment: (Thanks for the initial responses - I don't agree with possible dup though. The question broadly is: was the mod decision correct? Maybe there's a dup for that... `;-)`).

Comment: Ack I say if the guy wants to end it with God Bless, why not?  Why is it okay for some of you to have the profile pics you have but he can't say God Bless.

Comment: @JonH: he can offer as many blessings as he likes _in his profile_. And, in any case, that's not the only issue here - the problem is that he feels free to roll back other good edits, and has moderator support to do so.

Comment: @halfer - Your profile is literally in my face right now, so what's the difference?  Maybe you should leave the guy alone?  It's bad enough you linked him for all to see?

Comment: @JonH: you're a high-rep user, surely you know that profiles have long been treated differently to post content? Even material that is regarded as "offensive" is OK there, up to a point.

Comment: @halfer - to me it's not offensive...it's thanking or blessing someone...call me crazy but being nice is a nice thing once in a while.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @halfer, a little off-topic but your edit comments are respectively *Fix case, trim religious material (keep this up and you'll get a moderator flag)* (which is **way too hostile**) and *More grammar and apostrophes, less religion* (which is borderline). I'm not a religious person myself, but I believe you may have more success if you keep your edit comments more objective, rational, and less hostile and snarky.

Comment: @JonH We've been pretty clear that other niceties like "Thanks", and "Hello" are not desirable and should be edited out, as demonstrated in the link Clive posted. How is this any different?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It isn't.  You edit it out, you (optionally) leave a note informing the person of the ethos of low signal to noise promoted here, and if the user rolls back, it's not that huge of a deal.  Just move on.  There's tons more egregious nonsense going on that needs editing.  The last thing you want to do is get into a rollback war over two words.  So, yeah, what the mod said.

Comment: Also, I'm of the belief that the tl;dr goes at the top of the question.  I'm not that religious about it so I won't edit to fix.

Comment: I agree with FrédéricHamidi. The fact that the content is religious is *irrelevant*. The problem is that it is **noise**. Noise gets edited out. Posts that don't follow [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) get down voted. You'll likely get more traction with this user if you explain that it is against the rules. Including that link in your edit notes is usually effective.

Comment: @Will Sure, except that we've said, in previous Meta posts, that if the user is rolling back good edits, you should be flagging for moderator attention. Perhaps that advice should be rewritten to say, "You should be flagging for moderator attention only for things that the moderator will care about" and we can be left to wonder what those things are.

Comment: @JonH adding noise like "thanks" or "God bless" is __not nice because it is noise__.  On SO we say thanks with upvotes, accepts, or chat.  The posts need to be clear of as much irrelevant noise as possible.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I accept the criticism, thanks. The only minor point I'd make there is that the user in question had already ignored other people's views on the matter.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well, that happened.  And the mod said meh.

Comment: @halfer, that's where I second BSMP's comment -- you have to make that look as a community rationale, not as individuals' views or opinions. We, *globally*, have made a choice, we have reasons to back it up, and conveying that usually works. (Usually.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: apologies, would you expand on your last comment? I don't follow it, but would like to understand it. What global choice has the community made that you're referring to? (We are probably in agreement, and I'm happy to give way on the topic at hand).

Comment: @halfer, *noise* (note that you should *not* use that term in your edit summaries when dealing with sensitive content as it feels quite derogatory) is defined under the *Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings* section of our [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). The rationale behind that can be found on the Overmeta through [Clive's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320874/second-opinion-requested-on-user-rolling-back-changes-to-remove-religious-materi?noredirect=1#comment332529_320874). The community as a whole actually decided that back in the old days..

Comment: ...and it doesn't mean that won't change, because this very site is proof the community at large is still involved in decisions regarding *their* site (including possibly reversing previous ones). In the meantime, these are the rules *every user here, regardless of their gender, religion, or political stance* is dealing with.

Comment: Ah yes @FrédéricHamidi, agreed about noise, both in the sense it should be trimmed out, but that it feels a bit abrasive in edit messages. I am trying to strike the right balance between friendliness where someone doesn't know our hundreds of unwritten memes, whilst being a little harsher on posters that are a drain on the community (e.g. posts that say "This is urgent, I have a deadline of Monday" - I would estimate we get about 10-15 of these every day).

Comment: @halfer, do not go after those. That's a waste of your time and cannot possibly scale -- they are far more numerous than we are. Moreover, it might get you fixated on a frustrating routine that may ruin *your* life, not *theirs*. It is actually very possible [you need a break](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320874/second-opinion-requested-on-user-rolling-back-changes-to-remove-religious-materi?noredirect=1#comment332571_320882), or at the very least need to stop being so much concerned by the help vampires' problems.

Comment: @Frédéric: thank you for your evident concern, it is appreciated. My life is far from ruined though! I get a lot of pleasure from seeing the quality improvements I make, as well as contributing to a resource that has helped me a great deal professionally. I have no intention of ruining anyone else's life though - even vampires. Anyway, I will leave the discussion there - thanks again.

Comment: As someone with delete votes, I *love* noise phrases in questions. Because often a post with much noise also has other problems. An old post with noise is probably low value because a valuable post is likely to have been cleaned up.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of a question about rollback of edits. At heart it is a question about whether irrelevant religious material counts as noise.

Comment: @Raedwald: I agree that it's not a dup, but I've got an answer from a moderator that I'm happy with. On the one hand I think editors need to rely on mods to back up evidently correct edit decisions, but in this case I probably complicated it by expressing frustration in edit messages - even if it was clear to me that the OP was causing a nuisance deliberately.

Comment: If you imagine that `bless you` means [`you` are now a part of the current package](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html), it becomes humorous and partially relevant to coding `:)`

Comment: @Laurel: actually, I have a different explanation. Oddly, I'd found that every time I sneezed, the poster edited another one in.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I declined that flag because it looked to me like you were trying to start a fight with this user over some fairly trivial wording. It didn't seem worth it to escalate the situation, so I saw no need to step in and lock the posts or warn the user.

These weren't just edits to posts that you happened across as you were reading the site. You've been following this user around for the last couple of weeks and editing their posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36366483/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35518014/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35784697/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34811798/revisions

The last couple of edits you made had summaries of

> More grammar and apostrophes, less religion

and

> Fix case, trim religious material (keep this up and you'll get a moderator flag)

which I thought were needlessly aggressive, and looked to be provoking a fight. That's what I meant when I said that I didn't think this was worth arguing over.

Is that wording fluff that we'd normally edit out? Maybe. Personally, I think people go a little overboard with the removal of "Thanks", etc. from posts, when there are so many more pressing quality matters to attend to. In most cases, this wording doesn't hurt much.

I also recognize that some people feel very strongly about the way they've worded things, and I try to balance how much they're willing to fight for something against the importance of removing that wording. If it's not worth the fight, I walk away.

Before calling in a moderator about this, maybe try leaving a polite and non-threatening comment about why you think the edits improve their posts. They didn't roll back your older edits that removed more obvious religious content, so maybe without the aggressive edit summaries they would have left these alone. It might be worth engaging them person-to-person before calling in a moderator.

Comment: Not exactly following them around, no - I search for fluff markers ("urgent", "bless", "help ASAP" etc) and generally I find these to be a good mechanism for finding material that needs fixing. If I then find there is more than a couple of changes, I will edit. Thus this user has popped up in my editing history a few times because he was already adding in fluff material when someone else had asked him not to.

Comment: I will certainly try to trim down the sharpness of my edit remarks though - they are probably a sign I need to take a break. The quality of material here matters to me, and the increasing amount of fluff we get in posts feels like we either need automated tools to improve post quality, or we need to accept that millions of messy posts are inevitable.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts anyway - my complaint in this case is not a sign that your moderator duties are not appreciated.

Comment: I want to add one tiny thing to this. I would normally presume that the edit comment is better for communicating to the OP about pre-edit quality than the comment stack because you can't see the edit comment until you open the edit history.

Comment: @Joshua: edits on a person's posts are communicated to them using a notification icon, just the same as if they received a comment addressed to them. I _think_ the edit reason is added in the notification as well. However, I have seen so many people ignore edit notifications that I am not convinced they are a reliable method of communicating what was wrong with a post.