# Suggested policy change on handling deliberate writing errors

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks, custom-flags

Some readers will know that I am a keen editor on the main site (and that I probably spend too much time there). Over time, I have encountered a relatively small number of users who wish to insist on wilful and deliberate writing errors, probably for stylistic reasons.

I have raised this issue on Meta before in various guises:

- [Jan 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165504/can-a-literate-user-be-encouraged-to-stop-deliberate-writing-errors) - lower-case "mobile device" posting
- [May 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293779/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-encouraging-a-user-not-to-make-deliberate-writ) - lower-case "mobile device" posting
- [Apr 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320874/second-opinion-requested-on-user-rolling-back-changes-to-remove-religious-materi) - religious proselytisation

The summary of the responses were as follows (and I have taken them as a sort of *de facto* policy in each case):

- 2013: a moderator took the view that a "stylish" post can be flagged, if it is clear there is a pattern of deliberate errors over time
- 2015: the community seemed to have a shift in opinion, and suggested that it is better to try to repair some posts from the user in question, and it becomes a flaggable issue only if the user rolls back
- 2016: a moderator indicated that it is best to reason with a user before flagging for a moderator, and that in some cases, a moderator will side with the poster, even in the case of OP rollbacks of improvement edits (e.g. if discussion has become fraught, or that enforcement would be counterproductive in some fashion)

I admit this is not much data to be assuming a trend, and I appreciate that how a specific flag is handled depends on the moderator in question. However, I have a new case. Part of my post here is to draw attention to that case for the community's consideration, and is also to suggest an approach that moderators might take to gently encourage an adherence to technical writing.

### New deliberate errors case

So, the new case is as follows. I found a ~20K user<sup>†</sup> who is writing most of their posts in all-lower-case. I think this is irritating to read, and it is being done deliberately, so to me falls into a different editing category to the main source of errors (which is that the author does not have good English/grammar).

I edited a few of these, and found that some of them were being rolled back by the OP shortly after. I commented under one of their answers, and had a conversation, but this ended with no agreement reached (they did not seem to be amenable to a conversation).

I therefore flagged this:

> This high-rep user is writing some of their material in stylistic lower-case. I have repaired it, and it has been silently rolled back. Would you roll back again and consider issuing a warning? Thanks

I received this flag response:

> helpful - edit is not very important, let's leave it to answerer's wishes

So, while I respect the time moderators give to the community, I think this decision was wrong. The policy in this area is probably a bit woolly, given that it is impossible to codify everything in one place, but I think I respected the latest Meta advice in force:

- Didn't flag until I saw rollbacks
- Made a civil approach to the author to ask for readability fixes to be kept
- Flagged as a final solution

I *think* these actions correspond with the various bits of advice given on Meta over the years. I did ask the OP what the purpose of the mobile-phone posting was, but this question was entirely elided.

### What kind of writing quality are we aiming for?

Many years ago, Stack Overflow folks used to say something like:

> Stack Overflow is not a forum
>
> We're looking for technical writing here
>
> We're closer to Wikipedia than a chat-room

I agree with all of that, but perhaps it is changing? There was a hint in the recent culture-change blog post that perhaps we're editing too much here, and that chatty/stylistic/begging/txtspk/nonsensical questions are examples of individual free expression we should be encouraging.

I exaggerate a bit, of course, but the point I'm making is that it looks like the policy of insisting on high quality material is loosening over the years, and that either moderators are somewhat supportive of that trend, or they are burdened to the degree they can't enforce the level of quality they would like.

To some degree, I would be prepared to lobby for a tightening up of writing quality guidelines. It isn't realistic for Stack Overflow to mirror Wikipedia's editing quality, but their readability is certainly something we should be aiming for. I *think* the user community is of a similar mind, but it may depend on future changes of direction from the Stack Overflow leadership (since they may wish to go the other way, and loosen things further).

### Does any of this matter?

Good question! Well, a bit "yes", and a bit "no". I should say that of all the edits I have made on the site, I'd guess 99.9% of them are accepted without question (mostly because the OP has already left permanently, or doesn't care one way or another about the quality of their questions). So, that's a "no", mostly.

But, it's also a "yes", because it is dispiriting for editors to see their volunteer work thrown away, and it feels unfair that some people making wilful mistakes appear to be above the guidelines we apply to everyone else. While I enjoy improvement work, editing for quality here is probably already a fool's errand, and feeling like one does not have backup may be the final straw.

For what it's worth: I don't believe the moderators are actively biased towards high rep users, but I imagine there is at least some application of the idea that high-rep users producing useful content should not be alienated. There is a sort of trade-off arithmetic here: a heap of good answers written in an irritating fashion is better than no answers at all, if we assume that good answers written in technical writing is not on offer, and that a grumpy OP might prefer to ragequit than amend their style.

Of course, I could just try to let this not bother me, and to try to maintain a mental list of users whose material may not be edited. This is not out of the question, but I am conscious that if I try to be eminently reasonable with flag decisions, I create a situation in which it is easiest to decide against me, because it is suspected I will give way easily (i.e. the wilful writer is thought to be willing to kick up a time-consuming fuss).

### Suggested policy approach

I appreciate it adds to moderators' burden, but perhaps in these cases where the trend of stylish posting is unequivocal, a moderator could ping the author privately and ask them to switch to ordinary English writing rules. I would agree this might vary depending on whether the OP appears to be a native speaker or ESL.

It may also help to have some written material about this in the Help section.

In most cases - and there aren't many of these - I think a moderator sending a message will make a sufficient "nudge" to encourage a poster to improve the quality of their output.

If that is not possible, then I'd argue that at least rollbacks that are obviously improvements should be restored. I've been told in the past by one moderator that unequivocal improvements prior to an OP rollback will always be restored by them, but as I have said, this probably varies with each mod.

---

<sup>†</sup> - please don't go hunting for them, I am not looking to unleash a *Meta effect* voting phenomenon.

Comment: Seems appropriate advice to me, just a realistic way to deal with SO getting evermore harder to moderate.  If that forces editors to focus only on posts that matter then I'm all for that.  Not so sure if this is a wide spread problem but lately my Interesting page is getting seriously overloaded with uninteresting edits.  Used to be limited to the weekends but now it happens on regular work days as well.

Comment: @Hans: as something of an aside, I've proposed various ways to limit the noise on readability edits ([e.g. here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325787/may-we-have-a-way-to-edit-a-closed-question-without-bumping-it-into-the-review-q)) but there was either a workaround (wait five days after closure) or it did not get any bites from the product team (undoubtedly it is not a priority tweak).

Comment: Most ESL speakers accept their mistakes as mistakes and are usually appreciative of our corrections, so that's nice. Note that I say "most" for a reason...

Comment: I just leave such things and move on. Too many things to fix without getting bogged down on one or two has been my reaction when it has happened to me.

Comment: @Brian: yeah, I hear you. While this is sort-of about one specific case, I am also trying to dig into whether there is a trend that might discourage committed editors from maintaining the present level of effort. In other words, if there is an increasing sense that quality is up to each poster, including hostile rollbacks to insist upon personal style quirks, then editing for quality may be more of a never-ending battle than it already is.

Comment: Reading through this post, i had to check if it was me. Though i have rarely rolled back an edit, and always appreciative of someone who wants to correct my atrocious speelign and grandmars :P All-in-all, i think stack overflow deserves a hi sense of quality, and i agree with the spirit of this question

Comment: _i agree with the spirit of this_ rOFL

Comment: I think yes, this should be enforced. In the same way that we don't accept content in foreign languages, writing "styles" that can easily alienate both native language speakers *and* ESL readers shouldn't be allowed. If you want to write in a different style, that's for your personal blog.

Comment: Is the new case for relatively new posts, or are they several years old?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: they are for new posts, one of the rollbacks was seven days ago.

Comment: (There is a probably a long tail of mobile-phone posting going back several years though).

Comment: Speaking as a general user one of the most frustrating things to see on an answer is an edit from someone that wasn't the person who wrote the answer. It usually requires pulling up the edit history to see the real answer. If poor grammar is due to the device they're using to type on (aka a phone) then I can at least respect the fact that the came and contributed, particularly if it was a good answer.

Comment: @m12lrpv: you're opposing mutual editing completely, which is the antithesis of the approach that everything can be improved. It would also make quality an entirely personal decision, and things are not that bad at the moment - there are certainly some levels of poor quality that moderators will object to.

Comment: So, you're worrying about capitalization of posts while the front page is overrun with low-quality questions from people who struggle with basic spelling and grammar, and even more people who struggle with the absolute basics of programming? That's a good one. No offense, but I would suggest you do something more productive with your time than polishing content which is fine except for a few missing capital letters (not that english has many of those anyways).

Comment: @l4mpi: I (and the community) can surely worry about both. Your "no offence" does not save your message from its hostile tone. Please be willing to hear views that are different from your own (especially on Meta).

Comment: @halfer I've seen enough questions and answers edited incorrectly so as to cloud the technical message of the post to know that editing isn't always a good thing. I suspect many people are editing to make themselves feel important.

Comment: @m12lrpv I agree with the first part (editing needs care), but you do yourself a disservice with the second part (vague _ad hominem_ that doesn't shed much light). If you are indeed anti-editing, then great, your view has been recorded, but perhaps Stack Overflow is not for you. This platform has mutual editing built deliberately into the application and moderation tooling.

Answer (score 30):

The question's score is at odds with the answers' scores, so I suspect another opinion is needed. So...

### In the event of an edit war, the best version should be chosen

*This is the policy I personally go by, though I appreciate that Stack Overflow is different.*

What does this mean? Well, it means that instead of automatically deferring to the OP's version, those intervening in an edit war should usually<sup>†</sup> follow this procedure:

1. **Which version is better?** This includes:

   - Which is easier to read?
   - Which has the fewest "interrupting features" (bltanat spellling erors, Z̡̡͆ͭ͋ͯͮ̏ͥͬ̐̒̅̎͊ͬ͆͏̶̩̼̹̙͞ạ̵̡̨̡̠̜̺̖̹̮̎͐̈̔̐ͦ͐͞l̻͎͖͔̖̘̜͙̻̹̊̄̇̍̀g̹͓̱̞̠̠̹͖̈̌̾́̚̕͝ͅo̾͊ͨ̎͋͌ͫ̒̂̃̚҉̡͍̰͎̲̹̻͡  , L3tTe¬ 5ubst1tutiön, etc.)
   - Does the edit overstep the line of what an edit should do (e.g. changing a question or answer's meaning).

If that's not immediately evident:

2. **Which version is best supported?**
   This is about what the comments say; an edit war usually involves lots of arguing in the comments, so you'll probably find the reasons for editing. If it's "the answer had a typo that makes the command expand to `sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /`" then you should side with that version, but if it's "your example wasn't Haiku-compliant" you probably shouldn't.

If you still can't come to a decision:

3. **Use your judgement.** This usually takes one of two forms:

   - **Both versions have serious pros and cons.**
     If this is the case, you should make an edit that combines the best parts of each version.
   - **I don't really see the difference.**
     If the edit's *that* trivial, side with the OP. They put the effort into writing the answer, so they should get to decide trivial things like color v.s. colour.

---

<sup>†</sup>: I'm not proposing that anyone religiously sticks to this procedure. That'll just cause more problems for everyone!

Comment: I agree on spelling differences - we have long held that any recognised English spelling is fine, and should not be corrected. Other than that, I think we agree that readability should be king, which pretty much my whole thesis. However, it's not me that needs persuading - it's the Stack Overflow community team and/or the moderator team.

Answer (score 11):

When the content of a question has issues that won't be fixed, either because only the OP can fix them and they aren't going to or the OP won't allow others to fix them, down vote.

Just be sure not to vote serially on the user if you see their posts often.

I get that this won't change their behavior. However, in this specific case, this user has been discussed on meta before. They already know it irritates people and affects how people vote on their posts. They don't care. And in the general case, we should vote based on the content even if it doesn't change a user's behavior.

Any of the standard flags like "Unclear" or "Low Quality" are going to be considered overkill, if not flat out wrong, so you're stuck with just voting.

Comment: Sure, but downvoting is not much of a sanction, and it may serve as sufficient irritation to encourage the wilful poster to keep irritating people. In the current case, a high-rep user will know they can successfully appeal about serial downvoting.

Comment: Similarly you could not vote and leave a comment along the lines of _"I would upvote this answer, but it's so hard for me to read it in all lower case and that is preventing me from upvoting."_  (+10 = "yay!", -2 = "meh.")

Answer (score -8):

If the writing is on topic and contains errors the OP is editing back, the errors should probably be left. It's a pointless edit war and the OP is most likely more emotionally invested than you are.

Without getting into why I is capitalized, if somebody wants to capitalize you for parity with I, let them. It's pretty harmless. The guy who insists on all lower case and rolls back edits deserves his posts downvoted because now they're hard to read. Same for the guy who stacks too many grammar errors.

I don't want to state a policy on Zalgo or other things that are deliberately hard to read, but posting something that's hard to read rarely a good idea and deserves a downvote unless being hard to read is appropriate (it almost never is).

If it's wildly offtopic, prune whether it has errors or no. Though I'd be wary of pruning eight words off a five hundred word essay.

Comment: As I mention elsewhere, I do sometimes downvote for this behaviour, but I can only (knowingly) do it once per user, and so it probably has little effect (especially on established users willing to weather the odd downvote).

Answer (score -18):

> helpful - edit is not very important, let's leave it to answerer's wishes

I think this response is correct.

The usefulness of Edit to correct trivial English error is only in a **very limited** way. When google leads you to SO for a solution of your technical problem, you won't even notice the grammatical trivia in a post.

It is the technical content that matters. Editing to systematically correct another user's English error is a waste of time with no gain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would guess this view is not going to be very popular amongst the _Meta_ readership; one could argue that Wikipedia would be useful in all-lower-case, but we might not think of that as acceptable.

Comment: For what it is worth, I don't think that this view reflects the motivation of the mod choosing not taking the flag further. I think it was more about not alienating a person who is creating useful (if rather tatty) content (which is, in itself, understandable).

Answer (score -30):

> So, while I respect the time moderators give to the community, I think this decision was wrong.

Well, answer me this question: whose post is it? Does it belong to the community or to the person whose *name is on it*? We generally give right-of-way to the OP of a post. You may not like the results of that, but that idea is part of the reason why we don't let people "correct" the technical specifics of someone else's post.

Some people deliberately misuse English. Some people genuinely think English would be better if we capitalized "You" the way we do "I", and they will deliberately write all of their posts accordingly to attempt to normalize it. Even after being told English doesn't work that way.

The only way to stop things like this is to have some formal discussion about what constitutes valid English. And there are consequences to having some kind of language style guide. Do we want the Oxford comma or do we not? Do we really want people to have to care *what that is*?

And there are more practical concerns. How do we get people to read the style guide? Who is responsible for dealing with a user's violations of it? Is it really worth having moderators going around and locking posts to prevent someone from using their esoteric style? Do we want moderators suspending users if they keep rolling back such changes... *to their own posts*?

I say that, if a user's use of English makes the post difficult to read, and they revert any attempts to improve it (which don't change the meaning of the post), then that post's usefulness is diminished and is therefore probably deserving of a downvote.

But to engage in something you're suggesting, where we have moderators enforcing some kind of style guide? I don't much like that. It's not a good use of their already limited time.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with the implication of your question at the end - indeed I am interested in people's views here. However, for your first question - I don't believe much in question ownership. They are licensed to the community, both in letter and in spirit, and we have explicit guidance that "if you are not comfortable having your posts edited, this site may not be for you".

Comment: I personally would not like to see moderation rise to suspensions on this issue - but I have a belief that most people are reasonable, and would be willing to make a moderator's life easier by giving way, especially since mods are neutral third parties. How moderators approach OPs would be up to them, but there are surely diplomatic ways of doing so that are not threatening.

Comment: @halfer: "*I have a belief that most people are reasonable*" I have a belief that someone who clearly knows that capital letters exist and are required by English grammar, yet refuses to use them when asked to do so and even reverts corrections that fix them *is not reasonable*. This person's behavior can only be changed with *threats*.

Comment: (You will be pleased to hear I don't have a strong opinion on Oxford commas `;-)`).

Comment: I see your point about reasonableness, and my judgement is that the OP was not very "reasonable" when responding to my earnest requests. Nevertheless, I hold out some hope they would be more amenable and open when dealing with a mod.

Comment: @halfer: Also, this is not a question about "feeling comfortable having your posts edited". Again, we specifically give the OP the right-of-way in the presentation of their information.

Comment: Well, it may just be that we have different tolerances for low quality. The mutual editing guideline is ancient, and yet mods have in the past have indeed intervened where "personal style" has irritated more than a few people (and generally this has been successful). I guess, as a community, we have to decide where the line is...

Comment: @halfer: I'd say "irritated more than a few people" is key. If somebody is being *so* disruptive to the community with their actions as to have multiple confrontations with and/or trigger multiple flags from independent individuals in independent situations over time, that's when we step in. And when we do, it's usually about their refusal to cooperate, not about any grammatical quibbles.

Comment: True @BoltClock, and I know of a couple of cases where minor presentation issues caused a bunch of friction (one ending in suspension, and one ending in grumpily changed behaviour). I guess I'm interested in pondering whether there is a _de facto_ policy change here, given that I think this flag would have gone in my favour a few years ago. Hans could be right, of course, in that this is merely a result of scaling moderation to our present size.

Comment: The oxford comma is a given, no discussion needed.

Comment: Jumping straight from "always capitalizing 'you'" (which maybe 0.01% of writers do intentionally, if that) to "oxford comma" (close to 50/50 split) seems unwarranted. There's a vast chasm between someone who is attempting to change an inarguable, indisputed fact of English and someone who is just expressing one or another of a set of similarly popular preferences. Putting periods inside (or outside) quotes and spelling color with a U, are recognized variants of English and can be let alone either way. Capitalizing "you" and leaving "I" lowercase are not and need not receive any deference.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I only mentioned the "always capitalizing 'you'" bit because I actually know an SO user who does that, I tried to explain the issue to them with a link to an EL&L post on the matter to stop them, and they wouldn't (as far as I know, they never rolled-back edits where I un-captialized "you", but their new posts kept doing it), so I just gave up and accepted that reading their posts was going to be painful to me. But at no point did I feel that sic-ing the mods on them was an appropriate response.

Comment: We; d'o'n"t! need )an( explicit ,style: guide. There Are onlY So MANY commOnly accePted foRMs oF "Proper' english. People should follow at least one of them. I agree with (the rest of) the more practical concerns of trying to enforce this though.

Comment: The Oxford comma has a name, so it is NOT important.

Comment: Let's talk about Jeff Atwood's @TinyGiant S: [`-1 vote` or `-1 votes`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oWLP.png)?

Comment: @Cœur well technically... it would be 1 vote with a score of -1

Comment: @NathanTuggy Periods outside, period. Now the important thing are smilies. No matter where I put them, they always look wrong.

Comment: "Does it belong to the community or to the person whose name is on it?" Both, hence the ability to edit...

Comment: @Cœur AFAIK, it should reflect score, no votes.