# Can we have an official statement regarding greetings, salutations etc. please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, etiquette, help-center, signatures

I've participated once in a discussion regarding removing greetings, salutations and thanks from SO posts [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). Another discussion took place on Meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Both accepted answers and their votes *seem to suggest* that the community agrees that we should remove such clutter from posts.

Unfortunately, still from time to time the same discussion arises in different comment threads or someone "pings me" by continuing the discussion under my answer post.

Basically, the stance of people still discussing the issue boils down to:

[image]

One recent example is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it#comment487416_288179) - there were many more, sorry for not collecting them over the years. The point is that, even an accepted Meta post with many upvotes does not seem to be credible enough - especially in the case when I'm linking to a post I wrote myself (this is understandable).

But even when I point to the other Meta link the answer is the same, sometimes with examples of other people's posts/comments disagreeing with this policy (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it/288179#comment166182_288172) (deleted)).

Could we please settle this matter once and for all, for example by stating in a clear way in the help center that thanks, greetings and other mailing conventions and courtesies are discouraged (or even not welcome)?

I will also happily accept, if the SO's official choice will be to allow such formulas by deleting my accepted answer from the first discussion and encouraging someone to post a link to the official rule book.

What I think is important, is a clear decision with a credible source, one way or another.

Comment: I assume with *credible source* you mean not yet another answer from a community member but more like Joel Spolsky taking a stand on this issue?

Comment: @rene An answer from an employee or a moderator, stating that "it's official" would be probably enough, but as I explain in the question, an entry in the Help Center seems even better.

Comment: If SO is community driven moderation, why is an "official" statement needed?  The community has spoken via the votes on both posts your linked.

Comment: I thought the only issue here was the lack of handwork for cleaning up every occurring case of greetings or salutations. I happen to get rid of those while I'm already editing questions for other reasons. That particular discussion that you linked only seems to point out that such greetings will always keep showing up, even though they're not in accordance to this site. In my opinion, there is nothing else to be aware of from that discussion. I guess we just need to do our best, just as we currently have to handle off-topic and inadequate questions by hand.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "The community speaking via the votes" is not worth a bucket of warm spit.

Comment: Neither, by that logic, is a "rule", @torazaburo. No one reads the Help Center anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray You're right of course, but at least it's easier to quote than some long tangled thread and is bit more authoritative.

Comment: @BartoszKP Note that also even if removing salutation is not a problem, usually people with less than 2k rep are expected to do more than that to provide a significant enough edit. This is because they're edit require 5 votes to validate and so it's discourage to give them the reputation for removing a "thanks" in a post. So you shouldn't approve remove salutations-only edits on the edit queue.

Comment: I don't think I will ever understand why some people here are so obsessed over things like a simple "thank you"...

Comment: And there we go again... :D

Comment: If the post is of good quality otherwise, this seems like absolute madness to me too

Comment: How is 5 to 10 letters clutter?  Is civility and politeness not worth the space?  This is why tech people get a bad wrap. The ones that see no value in areas that would be considered "soft skills" IRL.  I work with people like that in my office and it's maddening.  Such things should not me such a button.  It's really not a big deal.

Comment: Even though it's a site rule and I usually like to make posts as useful and easy to "scan" as possible, I cringe when I edit out "Thanks", etc. from posts because I feel like I'm cramping the original poster's style or editing out some personal touch that I have no business messing with. I do it in adherence to the site's rules and to make a "complete" edit but to me it feels weird every time and I find this rule overly restrictive. Also FWIW I doubt that people would really abandon a page just because it said "thanks" (either an answerer or somebody coming from Google).

Comment: @LazyBear One could argue that tech people also get a bad reputation because some people see a community consensus, disagree with it, and then complain and deride that decision, instead of recognizing other people's perspectives.  Did you happen to participate in any of the previous discussions?

Comment: @Beofett  I did a while back, and I'm always amazed that simple (so long as they are brief) niceties irk people so much on these boards.  I agree that overly long greetings or thanks are unnecessary, but to complain or be annoyed by a simple "Hello community!" or "Thanks, that did it" seems a bit silly.  It's hardly spam.  Everyone here is clearly willing to help people and that is a fine thing.  I owe my Master's degree to all the guidance I received here.  So I say, without hesitation or shame, Thank You All.  I couldn't care less if that offends your sense of brevity.

Comment: @Beofett But your assertion about the "bad wrap" I was referring to is way off base. Tech people are seen (in general) as introverted, irritable, and cold.  It's almost a cliché. I have 25 hrs of mandatory "soft skill" training a year as a result.  Besides, while it might be a majority opinion, it is hardly a consensus if these discussions are still a thing. I digress, but my point is, it is not a big deal.  Consider saying Hi back, then answer the question.  Taking the compliment/gratitude, and maybe say "You're welcome" Or "No Problem."    You may have saved someone's bacon with your wisdom.

Comment: @LazyBear My "sense of brevity" is not "offended".  I am not bothered by these little additions, but neither are my sensibilities offended that the community feels they are noise that should be removed. As for it not being a consensus despite the overwhelming majority being in favor, simply because "these discussions are still a thing"... apparently we define consensus differently.

Comment: I also believe that being able to disagree with a subjective position without declaring it objectively wrong, or insulting the position, is a more important "soft skill" than adding noise to information.

Comment: @LazyBear Yet your soft skills training doesn't stop you from boasting about how you took what you wanted without following the rules, insulting the people who do follow them, and dismissing with "I couldn't care less why it bothers you"? Maybe .. you need the training?

Comment: You guys have got to ask yourselves... how do "Hi" or "Thank you" from SO users impede/impact/affect your experience or the experience of the entire SO user base... I mean how ridiculous can this website get now that we're complaining about greetings/salutations...

Comment: @Ryan I'm not complaining about greetings/salutations but about lack of respect for consensus. As you may see in my question I declared that either policy satisfies me, as long as it's clear and officially stated. I'm not sure why it's this way, but almost every person opposing the removal of taglines uses some kind of a ridiculous strawman argument ("complaining about greetings", "why do you hate politeness you introvert snobs", etc.).

Comment: There are always going to be users who will insist that they don't have to follow site rules they disagree with. Users who disagree with the close reasons, users who disagree with down votes, users who disagree with our ability to edit posts at all, etc. I wouldn't worry about trying to convince anyone still adding noise to posts after seeing there's a site rule against it.

Comment: That guy has 88 rep. With all due respect to him, why do you care what he thinks? He knows nothing.

Comment: The thing is that civilities do not come with these words @LazyBear, civility lies in the actions. If I were to say that your blanket statement is utter horseshit, thank you, would these last two words be civil? If someone doesn't have the tiniest bit of respect for the community and won't do the simplest google search, but adds thank you at the end of a post, do you really call these people civil? I certainly wouldn't, and would hope people would stop being so superficial and look at the actual range of the actions, not wether or not they clutter their posts with thank you's.

Comment: @BartoszKP Okay fair enough, my bad. You want clarity as to what's appropriate for the website. I gotcha. 

I do want to point out however that even though maybe you yourself are not against the use of "thank you's" etc. There do seem to be quite a few like that on this website.

P.S it wasn't a straw man argument since I wasn't arguing anything. Just making a statement lol

Comment: @Ryan You know, I would *love* to have this discussion with you again after you've done several thousand reviews, after you've actually seen what we're really talking about. Most of the people in favor of removing them, are actually people who have seen countless posts, and most of the people who say that removing salutations is nonsense, have not. Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier perhaps invest some time into something a little more productive than reviewing several thousands of other users' posts, for which you don't get paid.

Comment: The problem seems to be that people have the wrong idea about what Stack Overflow is. Greetings and salutations would be completely out-of-place on Wikipedia, yet no one thinks that's weird or finds that it cramps their style. The same logic applies to questions and answers here. We are doing essentially the same thing, we just present the information in a different format (discrete Q&A chunks, focused on specific issues).

Comment: @Cody Gray: Can you really blame them, though? On top of discrete Q&A chunks, our user cards are attached to each and every one of our questions and answers (and even community wiki posts have *someone's* name attached to it on the Q&A page, unlike Wikipedia where editor names only appear in the history).

Comment: *"[..]invest some time into something a little more productive than reviewing several thousands of other users' posts, for which you don't get paid."* - @Ryan - (1) Nothing you do on SO gets paid for; (2) It is *you* who thinks that reviews are non-productive; the fact is that this community is a *better* place because of people who contribute, and review is one important way to contribute. This place would have been a mess if it weren't for reviewers who contribute with their time, effort, and energy to make this a place worthwhile, those who you demean.

Comment: Tbh I wish robo-reviewers had the same mindset as @Ryan. Not saying he's one, since he's probably not going to be interested in reviewing *anyway*, but I wish there were *no* other rewards for reviewing than the inherent improvement it brings so those ilk will have no business poking their noses into stuff they shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I find it amusing that the people who are in favor of allowing fluff content because "its polite" seem unable to explain their position without being condescending or using words like "ridiculous" or "obsessed".  I guess courtesy is only valuable when other people are doing it.

Comment: What I don't get is why it's an issue.  Thankers gonna thank, reviewers gonna review.  Win-win. (@j08691: Soers gonna So.)   Unless someone is suggesting perpetrators (from either side) get banned, what's the difference?  Regardless of much more in-your-face rules and much stronger consensus, we still get low quality questions.  If we can't stop that, how are we going to stop this happening when the preferred behaviour seems a lot more debatable?

Comment: @mcalex The issue often arises in a form of edit wars, or pointless time-wasting discussions. Clear set of rules dramatically shortens these debates: "here are the rules, if you don't like them, try discussing them on meta or get out".

Comment: @jrh: This is no place for "a personal touch"

Comment: [Related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbG1t.png)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

This already exists in the Help Center: [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

> **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card,
> which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional
> signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the
> questions and answers.
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your
> interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

There's also the [FAQ: How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit), which some might find less "official" but is even more explicit:

> ## Remove 'Hi' and 'Thank you' - but only while you're at it.
>
> 'Hi', 'Thank you', 'Hope this helps', 'Thanks in advance' — these
> things are considered noise on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can't get any more "official" than this.

Comment: @ChrisF Right, "tagline" seems to cover this. I'll use this link, thanks :)

Comment: I would say that it would be helpful if this was in [ask] in addition to/instead of the behavior section...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I agree. It's location isn't exactly intuitive.

Comment: This doesn't mention thanks. Or pleading.

Comment: Now if we could only stop people from starting their questions with "So..."

Comment: @philipxy - Is a "Thanks" at the end really that different from a "Hello" at the beginning? Or a tagline? Given the comments on the question itself, it wouldn't matter if the Help were more explicit on this point. People are bound and determined to include noise in posts.

Comment: Yes, it is different. Both thanks and pleading could reasonably, and indeed more reasonably, be taken as not being signatures, taglines or greetings. A clear communication must be unambiguous, not just have *an* interpretation consistent with what one meant. "Greeting" doesn't necessarily include "farewell" and "pleading". Your quote & its page don't address the underlying/motivating fundamental/general *goal* of "no social interaction in questions/answers". People *wanting* to act correctly need clarity. People thanking & pleading *aren't ignoring* anything clearly said there.

Comment: I agree with @philipxy.  Words have meaning.  Thanks and pleadings may be similar to taglines and signatures, but they are not those things.

Comment: @philipxy: Don't know about thank-yous, but pleading just makes people not want to take you seriously anyway. Editing out pleading is *doing the asker a favor* by allowing readers to focus on their question instead of getting turned off by how desperate they are for help.

Comment: @j08691: I still have yet to find that user who started literally every one of their posts and comments with "So..."

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan if it was put in the how to ask page then it would also need to go in the how to answer page as well

Comment: @BoltClock I don't understand how that comment is a response to mine. My comments point out that the answer did not present any stackoverflow corporate policy against question thanks or pleading, which are surely included in (corporate's and) the question's ("etc", "clutter", "other") "discouraged"/"unwelcome" content. (Maybe you were thinking something like I was asking *whether* those things were unwanted.)

Comment: @Boltclock - the way to cure someone of starting all of their questions with "So ..." is to edit them to "Once upon a time ..." .  (Kidding :-)

Comment: Personally, I consider ending a question with "thanks!" / etc to be a form of a "valediction", or "closing" - just like "looking forward to hearing from you". See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65046/whats-the-opposite-of-a-greeting or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction . If we "ban" all salutations, then we should also ban all of these, at least just because it's a natural counterpart to the greeting and one looks odd without the other. Similarly, I consider short pleads like "Could you help me?" the same. Longer ones often contain question, so these are in grayish area.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl You don't need to consider them like that "personally" - they *are* forms of closing statements ;0

Comment: @StephenC Has to be "Once upon a time in the West".

Comment: A good reminder

Comment: @ChrisF "We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered." Well, the source code can be even more official.\