# Should friendly language and remarks be removed from answers?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

Stack Overflow has often been characterized as a challenging platform to contribute to, sometimes seen as unfriendly. This notion has been ameliorated with a new [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) that includes expectations like:

- If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming.
- Be inclusive and respectful.

I recently saw a [1367 character answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66446313) ending in a friendly "Hope this helps." be [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66446313/revisions) with the sole purpose of removing that phrase. The argument was:

> Stack Overflow is like an encyclopedia, so we prefer to omit these types of phrases. It is assumed that everyone here is trying to be helpful.

That makes sense in its own right, but I don't feel it is congruent with the attempted shift in making SO culture more "welcoming" and "respectful".

I know the help section on "[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" says not give an answer which just says thank you. And that makes sense, but not allowing a friendly remark which takes up just 1% of the answer, seems to take it too far.

There is a reason we say these things IRL. Yes, SO questions are eventually encyclopedic in nature, but when the question is actively being worked on it is social in nature. I think minor friendly remarks like this have their place here.

Was it correct to remove the friendly remark?

Comment: The downvotes are probably a visceral reaction to the phrase "hostile platform".  I had to steady my hand too and I like to think I'm pretty cool-headed about this.

Comment: I am now eternally filled with sad that that question is over on uber-Meta, @πάνταῥεῖ.

Comment: Thanks, I've now tried to make it less direct. I'm paraphrasing what people tend to say on other social platforms. I didn't mean to be divisive.

Comment: What people say on other social platforms *is* divisive, though.  I'd encourage you to choose your own words. :)

Comment: @Makoto Here's another one relevant from Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351588/can-we-have-an-official-statement-regarding-greetings-salutations-etc-please

Comment: Downvoted because I think the premise is completely wrong. Then changed my mind and upvoted because I agree with the question it asks in the title and the end of the body. Then decided that was too confusing and removed my vote.

Comment: Well, the point was to help make people see SO as more friendly, and want to contribute. Those who are put of by SO, probably aren't on SO. That was the point of explaining it from an outside perspective. But one thing I'm confused about, is the downvoting on this question in meta. I didn't expect it to be a "agree" vs "not agree" vote. Maybe I misunderstood. I'm interpreting it as I'm asking it wrong, or not a question which should be asked.

Comment: No I think your question's fine.  You're at least asking about it as opposed to assuming, so that's a +1 in your corner.

Comment: Turns out the question has been debate a lot before, so in that sense I shouldn't have asked. But I did try to search for it before asking. I get that it was closed.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen don't worry, Meta is an abyss, so unless the post is in the FAQ, you can easily find it only if have been around for a while. The best thing we can do to battle the fragmentation is to put beacons by dupe-closures in the hope the next person notices and takes the time to read the linked posts (they usually don't). P.s. Please don't be surprised the post being heavily downvoted - it is perfectly fine, but votes do work differently here (mostly because no one bothered to give us a better way to express agreement and disagreement software-wise).

Comment: "the attempted shift" Let's say that nobody really asked the community about it. It was just imposed externally and you cannot expect everyone to be convinced of it, or to even interpret it the same way. To me, being welcoming means explaining the rules as carefully as possible, for example explaining that brevity wins over decoration any time. Friendly means foremost that comments should be friendly.

Comment: To heck with friendliness. It is irrelevant. What we need is civility. Everyone needs to get along, one way or the other, without aid. What is far more important is that everyone is left free to do what the site encourages them to do, curation being the #1 thing which should go as smooth and unhindered as humanly possible. Any sign that someone does not understand this process and will throw things like "friendliness" in as a blockade to that process needs to have their expectations corrected as soon as possible. Perhaps we lack documentation and guidance there, or have worded it poorly.

Comment: If the target is being just civil, then the Code of Conduct might indeed need to be worded differently. I don't interpret "welcoming" and "friendly" as just being civil. The example in the Code of Conduct even uses terms like "Thanks for trying to help" when explaining how to word yourself. I don't see that as very different from saying "Hope this helps". That is the crux of my confusion, and why I asked here. That said, I now understand what is expected by the user base, and I have no problem following the sentiment here, avoiding frivolous friendliness in my posts and edits.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Yes.

The remark at the end didn't add anything else to the answer, and the answer could stand on its own without it.  There's nothing *un*friendly about the way the answer is presented without the sentiment, "hope this helps", nor did the edit intentionally go out of its way to make the answer unfriendly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll then follow the same guidelines when writing and editing answers. This one is even explicit about not saying 'Hope this helps': https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351588/can-we-have-an-official-statement-regarding-greetings-salutations-etc-please