# Why is text in the question body removed when removing punctuation?

Tags: support, bug, edits

I just came by this question: [React - Infinity Loop when updating a state inside useEffect function with dependency array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901808/react-infinity-loop-when-updating-a-state-inside-useeffect-function-with-depen)

First thing I did was try to remove the initial dot from the body content, but for some reason this also removes the "Hello, " part.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that questions shouldn't start with "Hello". There might be an automated system that removes them. But really, that's far from the only thing you should have removed. The greeting is noise, as is the "Thank you!" at the end. That's just from a glance, there might be more things to edit.

Comment: SO have auto-remove with Hello/Hi/Bye/Thanks etc

Comment: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776) | [Can we have an official statement regarding greetings, salutations etc. please?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351588) | [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160)

Comment: Also, a note - very likely the user started their post with a dot to *avoid* the "Hello" being removed. So, they introduced even more noise in order to retain noise in the post.

Comment: And remember that there are honest-to god women using the site as well.

Comment: That's a misuse of elitist, but I'd expect nothing less from the unwashed garbage that--sniff!--needs to ask questions.

Comment: Why are you not removing both words? Neither should exist in the body of an answer or question

Comment: @SecurityHound I just did! I didn't know about this before.