# What should I put in the edit summary when removing noise?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

I have been editing many posts recently using suggested edits, to try and obtain the Copy Editor badge, and I see a lot of the following phrases:

- "Thanks!"
- "Yours Truly,
  Hank"
- "Hi there!"

The answer to [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) says I should remove these types of phrases. More specifically, it says:

> Yes, absolutely remove such things.
>
> Anything that is not relevant to the question/post is noise and should
>   be removed.
>
> That includes salutations, signatures, 'thanks' and the kind of
>   content you have highlighted.

When I edit these out, I have been using the phrase "*removed noise*" in the edit summary.  I think that might be a little confusing or vague to the reviewer, and I want to be as clear as possible.  Is there a better description I can put in the edit summary when I edit these kinds of posts?

Comment: "removed unnecessary signature"? But in general, if you do edits to correct these, PLEASE make sure there's nothing else to fix in the post. Often I see "removed noise" to an edit, and there's still MAJOR grammatical or language issues that aren't addressed.

Comment: @davidism, you're a funny guy editing my question about editing questions. Bravo.

Comment: how about a link? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: I just lead with, "Removing fluff" ... ex: "Removing fluff, making small grammar fixes, improved readability." However, I never edit a post to just remove fluff. I leave that to the >2k rep users.

Comment: I just put "fluff removal" lol

Comment: "Noise is not necessary, please only include information necessary to reproduce the issue."

Comment: "Removed noise" is perfectly fine. Though I prefer "removed fluff", "defluffed", or simply not calling attention to that and concentrating in my edit-summary on the important part of what I did. TBH, my edit-summaries are getting more terse...

Comment: @Will I use link, but better one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I just use plain old:

> "Noise reduction"
>   .

If I'm feeling a little more verbose, I'll write something more like:

> "Removed: [insert removed thing/s here]"

If I'm feeling generous and I think the user will actually read it, I'll link to the related help center or meta post/page. For example:

[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

I haven't done it myself, but you could always [follow Random's lead and try something a little more creative.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/9314/random?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Answer (score 2):

The examples you give as noise can be separated into the following.

1. Gratitude
2. Signatures
3. Greetings

I would recommend that you say "*removed thank you*", "*removed signature*", and "*removed greeting*" respectively. I also completely agree with @Patrice in the comments above. You should always address the major grammatical or language issues if there are any, not just the fluff.