# Handling OP's pre-emptive, defensive instructions

Tags: discussion, questions

Many times I see an OP asking a question with attitude. Like:

1. Don't suggest Google.
2. Don't suggest this kind of solution. I don't want this.
3. Don't downvote my question before reading.
4. Don't suggest any SO link or other blog link.

How can I answer such a question? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789790/android-center-gravity-is-not-working-if-container-layout-is-in-a-scrollview) is one of them.

Comment: Does it and anything to or clarify the question? If not, [edit it out as fluff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Comment: The best thing to do is to disobey. If you see someone asking "please do not downvote this," it is a red flag indicating that it *needs* to be downvoted. Good questions don't have disclaimers like that.

Comment: Sometimes the questioner has certain limitations that make sense to him in his environment but not in general. This somewhats limits the general usefulness of the questions but doesn't make it offtopic. So point 2 is mostly okay. Point 3 goes without saying and Point 1 and 4 are actually the duty of the questioner - he should have researched the question thoroughly before. The linked question only shows 3 and 2, not 1 or 4?

Comment: @Trilarion: Point 2 is okay if it gives enough background to explain *why* a particular solution isn't useful in their situation. My experience is that the kind of constraint that prohibits Obvious Solution A also prohibits Obvious Solution B, but maybe not Obvious Solution C. Without knowing the constraints, answering such a question is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: As mentioned by Code Gray, a "Don't down vote" is generally a red flag, depending on how well written the question is and the wording / phrasing of the "Don't ...." I either tend to down vote, flag and move on, OR I quote the misguided sentence and explain in brief words why this isn't a good thing to write in your question.

Comment: Just apply your secret decoder ring.  "Don't downvote" = "I know this question sucks and I would DV it myself" => DV.  "Don't tell me to Google" = "I know I should have researched this problem first but I decided to not take the time" => DV.  "Don't post a link" = "I did research it and know that it has a common solution, just tell me more about it". => consider.   "I don't want this" = "I did research this problem, know that this is a solution but am looking for another one" =>  UV.

Comment: @HansPassant _"I don't want this" = "I did research this problem, know that this is a solution but am looking for another one" => UV_ but only if the reasoning is explained, so it will be clear if a suggestion will be a more appropriate approach, but the explanation itself might show weaknesses in the logic or understanding.

Comment: In the case of 1,3,4, I would not even waste a millisecond on pondering such a question before downvoting and moving on.  'Don't suggest this kind of solution. I can't use this because blah' my well be OK, though.

Comment: @MartinJames I am completely agree with you.

Comment: "Please read details before downvoting/answering" is a perfect way to make me downvote a question I otherwise wouldn't have. Not that the question linked in the OP is such one.

Comment: @Magisch If that makes you downvoting, then I would say you are not judging the content of this question but include at least some heuristics about the quality of other questions with a similar comment. For me it's a bit different. Reading something like "Please read details before downvoting/answering" would actually make me read the question more carefully, not because the comment says so but because I would be slightly sceptical - however in no way a downvote would follow automatically, probably be a bit more likely though.

Comment: @Trilarion: I usually downvote when I see noise like that, then edit it out, read the question, and revert the downvote or even upvote ___if___ warranted. Most of the times, the downvote stays, though.

Comment: @Trilarion I see it as disrespecting of both me and my time, but I know a rude flag wont fly, so I downvote and forget instead.

Comment: @Magisch "Disrespecting"? - That is a bit too much in my opinion. Next thing you will downvote anyone with a spelling error because of .... Also, you kind of ignore the editing possibility. But of course you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @Trilarion I care a lot about intent. I will often fix and overlook many things for someone who is genuenly willing to listen and appreciates feedback. When someone sticks such a disclaimer in there it indicates 2 things: 1) They know their question is trash and they know the site rules, 2) they think they and their question are just _so much more_ important that the rules supposedly don't apply to them. I consider that a little (alot actually) disrespectful. I usually try and assume good faith but a disclaimer as this is a direct indicator to the opposite.

Comment: @magisch There we have the reason for the different views of us. I think there are alternative explanations for the disclaimer: it could also be a sign of: 1) uncertainty about the quality of their question, 2) bad experience in the past, which I would not consider really disrespectful and also not as a sole reason for downvoting. But it surely is a very subjective thing. One considers something as impolite, another one not.

Comment: "Don't downvote me" = "Don't tase me bro!"

Comment: Please don't downvote this comment guys. I worked really hard on it. :(

Comment: @Magisch "They know their question is trash" Actually they put disclaimers like that sometimes because they know this site is trash, and is filled with illiterate people who misread questions and go off on a tangent that's completely unrelated, or suggests dumb things like "google it".

Comment: There's no point in adding a "please don't downvote" comment to a question, ever. At best, it makes people read the question more critically than normal (making a downvote more likely, since people will be looking for things to downvote for). In the worst (and typical) case, it will prompt a "don't tell me what to do" reaction, earning an automatic downvote - that's human nature. And if the question is truly a good question, "please don't downvote" isn't necessary in the first place since you'll (theoretically) only get upvotes.

Comment: It's like this: many SO contributors have a life and, unfortunately, work. This leaves some little time left over for, say, looking at questions on SO.   There are so many questions, and SO MANY bad questions, that any quickly available clue to help direct attention is acted on.  Phrases such as those suggested by the OP are an immediate turn-off, and moving on to look at the next question immediately is the likely outcome.  I cannot understand why so many posters actually think that we have time to read everything that is posted when they put up signs 'BAD QUESTION AHEAD ;(

Comment: @AaronLS: at 18.5k rep, you have quite some time invested in "trash"...

Comment: #2 is fine. Those restrictions are usually present due to a constraint, and the OP wishes to save your time in answering. For instance, if the 99% answer is "Use Angular" but their shop has a "No Angular" policy, then perhaps they already fought that battle and need a different solution. In that case, all "Use Angular" answers are a waste of both person's time.

Comment: @Cerbrus No.  I haven't invested time in trash.

Comment: @MartinJames I think that's a good approach.  If you judge a question based on a couple short disclamers only, instead of actually reading the content, then it's better for everyone involved if you move on.

Comment: @AaronLS - it's not just me - that is inevitably how users sort questions on SO.  There is no time for anything else.  I challenge you to find a single question with shields of type 1,3,4 that is not very low quality.

Comment: Is "Don't suggest Google" valid for askers located in the People's Republic of China, which is known to block Google services at the border? Or is SO unusable in China anyway because of Google reCAPTCHA?

Comment: @DamianYerrick: Someone form China may have to answer that, but that might be difficult, if they can't access SO. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446523/amount-of-users-from-china) seems to indicate it's no problem to access SO, though.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Most comments like that add nothing to the question, and ***should be edited out***, as it's noise. As [@Anders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2200659/anders) suggested in the comments, a comment explaining why text like that is considered "noise" would be a valuable addition.

Noise like this is often a good indication there's probably something wrong with the question, though. So, have a good look at the question.

***However***, Make sure the comment *really* is noise.

Things like:
*"Don't suggest this kind of solution. I don't want this."*
Can actually have a good reason, even if it's poorly worded.

Comment: Sorry, had downvoted before I reached the disclaimer, I suggest putting it at the top.

Comment: The punchline is always at the end.

Comment: ... if there is a punchline. And the OP (or really anybody else) never appended anything else. ;-)

Comment: Btw. the editing proposal should also apply to "please do not downvote" or "why the downvotes". Instead of disobeying and additionally downvoting as proposed above, the better solution would be to just edit it out (and have a look at the question and downvote if the remaining part warrants it).

Comment: Apparently, 2 people read the complete answer, _and_ downvoted it ;-)

Comment: I agree. The only acceptable constraint, out of the original 4, was #2.

Comment: I would like to add that if you feel like it you can also add a comment explaining why that kind of instructions are frowned upon. Not mandatory, but helpful to OP if you feel you have the time and energy. Also, please dont downwote this comment. Wait, you cant! Ha ha! I win!!!

Comment: @PittsburghDBA Yep - though there should be a rationale so that people actually know why and can adapt.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the cited instructions are indeed pretty obnoxious, but I want to say a few more words about "Don't suggest this kind of solution. I don't want this."  If you believe that a poster is wrong to say this, you are being very, very bold.  You are declaring that you know more about the poster's circumstances and needs than the poster does.  You are presuming that the poster doesn't just need help with his question, but that he needs help -- your help -- even figuring out which question to ask.

Now, some of the time, it's true, posters are really uninformed and really confused, and they really shouldn't be ruling that particular solution out.

But other times, the poster knows perfectly well about that solution, knows that it will not work for them, and knows that you are about to suggest it -- which is why, to save time, they explained up-front that they couldn't use it.  By ignoring them, by suggesting that they *have* to use that solution whether they want to or not, you're helping no one, all you're doing is showing off your preconceived notions about what's acceptable or possible.

There's a related situation where a poster says "I want to do X" and a bunch of alleged experts pile on to declare that "X is impossible" or "X is a bad idea; you shouldn't even want to do X". This, too, can be intensely annoying and insulting to the original poster.  If he didn't *need* to do X, he wouldn't be here asking about it.

In many cases, I believe, when a poster says something like "I know the conventional wisdom here is to use solution S, but I have a specific constraint and can't use S", or, "I know X is generally considered impossible, but I want to take a stab at it, can anyone help?", and if you believe that S is truly the only way to go or that X is truly impossible, the right thing to do is just move on.  Don't downvote the question, don't move to close it as off-topic, don't post comments or answers declaring how wrong the poster is for asking that way.  Maybe they're not wrong. (Maybe you don't know everything.)