# Make opening sentences in questions more informative

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions

Many questions start with sentences next to noise, like "this is my first time encountering this ..." etc. which is quite annoying because exactly those opening sentences are shown in many lists.

Should such noise be edited? Or even better: shouldn't https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic contain some remark to this end?

Comment: "I am writing an app in Flask (Python).".  No way, your question tagged with a Python framework is about you writing something with that framework in that language?  I never would have guessed.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: The info on that sort of thing being noise is on [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). I can see adding that under the list of "Common reasons for edits" on [How does editing work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: When editing it out, I find it helpful to include the link to the behavior page. It seems to decrease the chances of the OP either rejecting the edit or adding the noise back in. (I used to point out that sentences like "I'm new/I don't know what I'm doing" attracts down votes and that seemed to work too.)

Comment: Should the question title be included anywhere in the body? I'm starting to steer away from including it as the first sentence, though.

Answer (score 8):

> Should such noise be edited?

Yes.  It's always been policy that you should be editing noise out of questions.  It's all the more useful if it's how the question opens, but it's still worth doing even when it's elsewhere.

> shouldn't https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic contain some remark to this end?

No, that's where we explain what is and isn't on topic here.  This wouldn't belong on that page.