# Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?

Tags: support, faq, editing-help

I asked a question on the [main site](http://stackoverflow.com) with the words "Thanks (in advance)"/"Thank you" at the end. Later on, a user edited them out!

- Why is this done?
- Should I [rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876/329351)/reject the edit?
- If it's not OK to say "Thanks" in a question, what's the appropriate way to thank the answerers?

I couldn't find anything about this in the [Help Center article on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: Also related: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: I downvoted for lack of research, then saw this is an FAQ entry. Maybe my comment will make that more apparent to others as well.

Comment: Also related: [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: strongly related: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/839601)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

### Why is this done?

Removing "Hi", "Thanks", "Appreciating any help", etc. makes questions more valuable for their future readers by making them look less like problems that only happen to their askers. We care about the future value of questions and answers because of this one key difference: **Stack Overflow is not a forum. It's a library of specific programming problems and their solutions.**

In addition, [thank-yous are assumed to be noise that can harm a question's readability.](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021)

### Should I rollback/reject the edit?

Don't do it *just because* the edit removes thank-yous. The following situations (**that are completely unrelated to editing out thanks**) can cause an edit to deserve a [rollback](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback/18876#18876) or a rejection:

- The edit conflicts with your intent
- The edit [ruins the post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302819/what-to-do-with-a-user-defacing-or-even-spamming-his-own-questions) or [introduces spam](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326981/is-this-link-in-a-question-a-shameless-plug)
- The editor is trying to answer your question or comment on it
- The edit fixes the problem your question is about (such an edit should be an answer) or introduces new problems

### If it's not OK to say "Thanks" in a question, what's the appropriate way to thank the answerers?

All you have to do is to [accept the answer that solves your problem!](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Doing so prevents the question and its answer(s) from being [automatically deleted](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

It also used to move the answer above all other answers (except when [accepting one's own answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) until this behavior was deprecated as part of the [Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/11407695).

Additionally, you can upvote good answers if you have more than 15 [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), so that they move up among all answers and become visible to more visitors.