# Will an editor's edit explanation go to the specified user in the explanation?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, email

Suppose you suggest an edit, and in the explanation box type something like:

*”@username Corrected some spelling.”*

Will the message go to the username's inbox? (I, for one, don't intend to; I am just curious.)

Comment: Nope - it won't.

Comment: I think (I'm not sure) that your (suggested) edit will appear in their Responses\Revisions page, e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=revisions). It may only appear once the suggested edit has been approved though. Using @ to mention them won't do anything though.

Comment: It only works in comments, and not always even there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no one will be notified when you use @UserName replies in edit descriptions. The *only* places where @UserName replies work is comments and chat. They don't work in posts (questions and answers), either.

For more information on how comment replies work in comments, see: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on the über Meta site.

They *shouldn't* work in edit descriptions. We're programmers here, so think of edit descriptions as the summary descriptions that you use when checking-in code to your source control system. The *who* is tracked elsewhere. The revision history shows who made the edit, who wrote the original, etc. All the edit description needs to do is explain the *why*—why did you make this change?

Some examples of good edit descriptions/reasons/summaries:

- "Removed 'thank you' and other noise."
- "Clarified that the problem only occurs on Windows."
- "Inlined screenshot and fixed code formatting."
- "Improved grammar to make post easier to read."
- "Trimmed begging/urgent pleading, which is unwelcome on Stack Overflow."
- "Removed irrelevant and off-topic rant about downvotes."
- "Reworded to remove expletives. (I understand you're frustrated, but this site requires professional decorum to be maintained at all times.)"
- "Applied proper blockquote formatting to excerpt from MDN documentation."
- "Removed improper use of inline code formatting: inline code formatting should only be used for *code*, not for emphasis."

Comment: @AnnZen https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions

Comment: [Salutations, signatures, 'thank you', and other types of fluff should all be removed from posts here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). If you think of this site as being more like Wikipedia (a place you go to find high-quality answers to programming questions), then it makes more sense. It isn't about the people; it's about the content.