# Validity of edits made to questions

Tags: discussion, edits

I am curious as to the motivation behind some edits made, also so that I can ask better questions from scratch. For example, I made a question where someone edited a name of a software from matlab to MATLAB (seems unecessary but makes sense) and edited my code (altough I'm not sure why because I copied it straight from MATLAB, but I accept it may have been necessary). However, they also deleted the final sentence of my question where I thanked in advance. How is that relevant or necessary? Shouldn't I include that in the end of the questions?

Comment: [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions). As for the code: You used a undefined variable. The edit added the variable to produce a runable code sample. Your code probably needs another edit because I doubt that the final ````` is really part of your code.

Comment: I edited that post. MATLAB is the official product name, hence I used that. Second, you missed a new line after the opening code fence, hence it didn't render the first line; I didn't remove any code. I did miss the closing code fence, that should've been moved to a new line as well, apologies. Otherwise, the "I don't have MATLAB any more" part has no bearing on any possible answer, hence it's "noise" as in: just distracting and irrelevant. Finally, I'm not a fan of bold formatting, as it makes stuff stand out stronger than necessary IMO. Proper sentences should serve for emphasis.

Comment: My real issue was the "thank you" part, as I believed it's polite to say it in the end of a question, but I have read the linked question in the comment above, and altough I don't agree with it, I will follow the guideline to make the question more readable. As for the bold, I believe it's really up to the asker of the question how they want to give emphasis and I usually use it, both on forums and when writing scientific texts, but I understand it may seem unecessary. Thanks for your prompt response!

Comment: If the "thank you" part is the only issue you had, re-adding that, rather than rolling back the entire edit, would've been the polite way to handle that. Only if the edit deviates from your original intent, or if it vandalises, adds spam etc, roll back (sse the link BDL posted). If it's a good edit by and large, with a small thing you don't agree with, just change that separately. Edits should strive to make the post a better/more readable fit for SO, which is precisely why others are allowed to make edits.

Comment: Small side-note, you can reply to people in comments using `@<username>`. [This also works to ping editors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/325771), i.e. you can ping me on the question itself as well (even before I hadn't added that comment).

Comment: See also *[No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it/385424#385424)*.

Comment: *"Thanks in advance"* is seen by most readers as *insincere* politeness or a form of unjustified entitlement (***demanding*** an answer, masqueraded as politeness). That it is so often misspelled (blindly copied/mutated from other posts) just shows that it is something that is just tagged on for the effect, not actual thankfulness. In fact, using *"Thanks in advance"* can be considered rude.

Comment: In any case, meta information does not belong in the question. That is what comments are for (despite the name, "comments").

Comment: @PeterMortensen I thought comments were for clarification questions, or relevant information to the poster, not meta commentary or "Thank you"'s

Comment: [More eloquently expressed](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/thank-you-in-advance/): *"On the other hand, “Thank you in advance” can come across as presumptuous and even passive-aggressive. Depending on the context, it could make Susie sound as though she’s saying, “I expect you to do this.”"*