# How questions are responded to here

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Undeclared Identifier (apparently)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77347097/undeclared-identifier-apparently)

I find a lot of good answers here on Stack Overflow, but I have a very difficult time interacting with this community.

Take the question above for example. I was asking about a problem with the IDE. There is no error code given to me to share. I included the entirety of the error message I was given which is "undeclared identifier".

I explained that the error message is wrong and asked how to get the program to display accurate information.

In response, I was downvoted numerous times, and my question was closed because I didn't include information which I either don't have, or is irrelevant.

As I said in the original question, the code works fine. It is not a coding problem, it is an IDE problem. Including working code will only confuse the matter more.

I don't want to fight with anyone, and I shouldn't be treated this way. Every time I'm on this site, I feel like I have to walk on eggshells. Sadly, my best efforts are not good enough.

How do we get past whatever the problem is, so that myself and others get the answers for our questions?

Comment: I mean... i assume people want to come to the conclusion that it's an IDE problem on their own, rather than trusting the word of a user who seems to have an issue they can't solve. Try to look at the question from our perspective.

Comment: Some code would really help people reproduce and understand the problem there. Even if we agree to it being an IDE problem an IDE might react differently to different code so asking for code doesn't seem to be a problem to me.

Comment: At very least you should edit that question to clarify if it is compile-time or intellisense error... maybe want to include screenshot if it is indeed intellisense. Creating, verifing and including real MRE into the post is pretty much always good idea - not really sure why you are so against it.

Comment: There are too many unknowns if you don't include the actual code. For example, as in if it can't be immediately reproduced by others, is it due to differences in the code or in the configuration of Visual Studio? Please help those who are willing to help.

Comment: Side note: it also helps for reception to adopt a bit more humble style of writing... It is a good idea to *assume* you are doing something wrong rather than an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) with 40 years of history being wrong all the time... even if indeed there are bugs in VS.

Comment: You may be jumping to conclusions: 1) you state that you have an IDE problem without demonstrating proof of this. Perhaps it is *not* an IDE problem. 2) You assume that you are being mistreated with regards to the response to your main site question, and perhaps your question really is deficient and could use more information and evidence. Please look at all sides of the equation.

Comment: *There is no error code given to me to share* if it is really a compile error (and not an intellisense error) there is **always** an error code in the error list and in the output window. If there is non, then show a screenshot of the error list and post the compile log from the output window.

Comment: See it from the perspective of people who work for a decade with a certain IDE and a person who you don't know drops in and claims something where you are very sure that it's impossible. Wouldn't you first ask for some kind of evidence first? Especially when there is no method given to reproduce the same behavior?

Comment: You were not downvoted. Your questions was downvoted.

Comment: This question being downvoted, yet no one has listed any syntactic problems with it, makes it hard to believe it isn't personal. Perhaps the website should be updated. There's no point writing out good questions with lots of text for you all to refuse to believe it and demand screenshots and code.

Comment: @SomeGuy69:  We've made it clear that it's not you personally that's being attacked. Please don't twist our perspective into that we're against you.

Comment: @BDL The text content should be given as text whether or not an image is there for further info. Moreover the presence of an icon can be given via text. What can be given by text should given by text. I'm done now.

Comment: Voting on meta posts includes up/down for agreement/disagreement on a proposal or viewpoint. PS Please act on all the feedback at main & meta (instead of denying it's there) if you want your main question to be opened & answered. Please learn how the site works. [tour] [help]

Comment: Generalization doesn't work either. It is (much?) harder to ask a well-received C++ question than it is to ask a well-received Python question. There is not one "community" to point a finger at, but there is a noticeable difference in how strictly questions are curated depending on their main tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This is not a discussion forum nor a help desk

> I don't want to fight with anyone, and I shouldn't be treated this way. Every time I'm on this site, I feel like I have to walk on eggshells. Sadly, my best efforts are not good enough.

> How do we get past whatever the problem is, so that myself and others get the answers for our questions?

The purpose of posting on Stack Overflow **is not** simply to resolve a specific issue that affects your specific project. The purpose of posting on Stack Overflow is to help contribute to a collaboratively edited reference library in Q&A format.

**Absolutely nothing involved in this situation is about you**:

- Downvoting questions isn't "treating" the person who asked them in any particular way; it's registering that the question is counterproductive to the goal of building that library. As such, there is no question here about how you "should be treated".
- Questions are held to high standards, because we want people who find Stack Overflow with a search engine to see high-quality content - both question and answer - that they can *immediately* check to verify that it matches the problem *they're* encountering, and then see a solution. But we absolutely do not expect *users* to walk on eggshells; we only expect them to:

  - uphold the Code of Conduct;
  - learn from question feedback, edit questions to improve them accordingly and ask better questions in the future.

  The attitude that one should "walk on eggshells" is in fact counterproductive - because we [do not want](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/) questions to include social niceties, "update" or "edit" sections, or other forms of "replies" to comment feedback. We only want them to be improved, taking comment feedback into consideration.
- There is no "problem" here on a social level, because we don't really know who you are, and have no particular interest in learning about you - we are interested in the question. The only thing that matters, in terms of "getting the answer", is that the question meets site standards. The primary reason for answering the question isn't to help you, but to contribute the other half of a Q&A entry for the library.

If you approach Stack Overflow with the attitude that there is only value in the site when you "get the answer for your question", then you have missed the point entirely. It is only even "your" question, in the first place, to the extent that you license the content to the site and it is attributed to you in accordance with that license. If the question is useful to the site, that is because it could help someone else with the same problem. Such other people will not care who you are.

### Understanding and representing problems

> As I said in the original question, the code works fine. It is not a coding problem, it is an IDE problem. Including working code will only confuse the matter more.

> There is no error code given to me to share. I included the entirety of the error message I was given which is "undeclared identifier".

This is a contradiction in terms. It became clear through the comment feedback and discussion here that you were not talking about Intellisense, but instead about what happens when you try to build and run the program using the IDE. The IDE includes its own compiler, and told you about what happened when it tried using its compiler to compile your code: that compiler reported an error (technically, it reports two, but that's only because it's designed to give an extra "Build errors occurred" when there are any other errors). That means, **the IDE's compiler told you that the code does not work fine**.

It is important to understand that just because a program window pops up **does not mean** that the code compiled and built correctly. Sometimes IDEs, when told to "build and run", will run the last working version of the program if the build fails.

> There is no error listed in the build output. The code works. The project builds and executes correctly.

> To try to fix this, I added the declaration to the header file SpaceConquestD2D.h. It shouldn't be necessary as there is no build error, and did not resolve the error in the error list.

Again, in the question itself you contradict yourself. The error list that you show in the screencap **is** "the build output". The error that was shown to you **is a build error** - (re)compilation is a part of building. The project **is not** compiling, building and executing correctly, because that **entails not** seeing any errors in that list. If you see correct execution, it's of a different executable (possibly based off a previous version of the code).

### Making problems understandable and diagnosable

> and my question was closed because I didn't include information which I either don't have, or is irrelevant.

It's practically impossible for any programmer to understand any practical problem without being able to reproduce the problem. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) allows a proper examination of the situation, and allows for *repeating* that examination after trying various things, which therefore allows *diagnosing* the problem. This should consist of code that someone else can **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything**, in order to see the **exact reported problem, directly**.

The screencap shows that your actual source file runs at least 276 lines of code - that's clearly more than is needed to demonstrate the problem. It is **[your responsibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) before posting** to try to figure out what parts are relevant, and try to create such a MRE.

Can you copy and paste all your code to a new project and still see the problem? If not, then that's part of the investigation. Maybe something in your project file is corrupted. (On the other hand, if that fixed the problem, then there is nothing more to ask about, right?) If you can, then figure out what parts of the code are actually **necessary to reproduce the problem** - never mind any of the original planned functionality of the project.

If you cannot create a proper MRE *then you are inherently not in a position to know* what information is "irrelevant". If you do not have some missing information and cannot figure out how to get it, *that is not our problem*; necessary information is necessary information, and there's *certainly* no way that *we* can get it for you.

Comment: Great answer. Makes it very clear that this site is only interested in itself. Can't wait for it to be replaced by A.I. doing a much better job.

Comment: @SomeGuy69 **if** AI ever becomes able to do a "much better job", my immediate concern will be for the continued existence of the human race. This site is interested in the goal that it sets out in the tour, and having that interest is necessary to accomplishing that goal. If you think that having a superpowered search engine that handles natural-language queries well is useful, by all means continue to use AI (but don't blame us when it gives you code that doesn't work or is dangerous, because **it fundamentally does not understand** its output). Our goal is producing the searchable content.

Answer (score 26):

To your specific problem:  sometimes IDEs don't report things correctly, for one reason or another.  I work in Java and leverage Apollo generated code, but that causes my IDE to complain and think that there's no classes/identifiers, but Gradle is able to find it.

The real challenge with a question like this:

- You're assuming the IDE is at fault and not your code
- You don't put out any additional information about your code
- You don't specify if you're using any additional build tools besides just the IDE to see if they're also erroring out

...so it's kind of clear why the question gets downvoted.  People can't really get an understanding of what's going on to figure out enough to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better answer. I still disagree that I'm assuming where the error is, though. Sorry to hear that people can't understand what I wrote. I'll update it and hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: _"Sorry to hear that people can't understand what I wrote."_ It's not that people _"can't understand"_. They disagree, or you made your point poorly.