# Should I accept a bad answer or write my own?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I recently posted a fairly standard Stack Overflow question about how to use an existing library to accomplish a task. (I'm being purposely vague to avoid shaming the answerer.)

I didn't receive any answers for a few days, and eventually after googling for a day, I found what seemed to be a solution, which I implemented and began testing.

Then, when I had actually forgotten about the question, I noticed that someone had answered it. Their answer was the unfortunately common "no sandwich", where they start by saying it's not possible and explain why for a bit, give the answer, and then end with saying it's not possible and that I should do something else. Their middle answer was correct though, and linked to the *exact* file I already used to implement my solution.

I think technically their answer is correct (it is literally what I did), but I feel like it is the worst version of the answer. If I upvote it, other people asking the same question might only get two paragraphs into the answer and then give up, thinking it is not possible.

Should I post my own version of the answer, with the irrelevant details excluded, just providing the answer? I think I can also provide an example and overall improve the answer. My main concern is that it will very much look like I just copied their answer and am trying to avoid marking them as the accepted answer by answering the question myself.

***Information***: My question wasn't asking to do anything that was a bad practice, such as calling undocumented Windows functions. I think the question just required combining two technologies, where the answerer was very familiar with one, and not familiar at all with the other. So naturally their response was skewed towards what they knew, and away from the technology they weren't that familiar with.

Comment: Never select an answer you haven't tested and aren't satisfied with.

Comment: Any time you have a better answer or an effective work-around if there is no direct answer, and you can prove it, formally write it up and add it to the repository.

Comment: @user4581301 I guess the point is that the OP knows for sure that the answer works and is satisfied with the solution, and they don't have a better answer or workaround, just that they think the current answer, while correct, is phrased in a misleading way and therefore might fail to help other people. However, writing a better version is not really an option because the solution would be essentially the same, just described better.

Comment: @ yeerk I'd say leave a comment under the answer and hope that people see that. When I'm reading an answer that says "not possible" I always check the comments for further leads, there is often valuable information to be found. Then you can accept or upvote it, given that it in fact does answer your question.

Comment: @Marijn On re-read I see your point. This might be a job for an edit to move the work-around to the top and the explanation of why the direct route does not work to later in the answer. Basically, "You can't do what you want, so do this instead. Here's why."

Comment: 1) why would you ever accept an answer you think is bad? 2) If you could write a non-trivially better answer than an existing one, why wouldn't you?

Comment: *"(I'm being purposely vague to avoid shaming the answerer.)"* - FYI: mentioning that it is a recent question and what the question is about is kind of counter-productive to your (poorly worded) goals, meta dwellers don't need much to find what you're talking about.

Comment: I was in a similar predicament myself on SO and Unix.SE multiple times. You shouldn't be discouraged to post your own answer if you know it is better, and does not use the usual "it's not possible" answer. I feel like the status quo seems to nearly always be into upvoting/accepting answer to either: 1. Whoever has the most reputations, regardless of the quality of the answer, 2. Whoever post first, without testing said answer to see if it work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> I'm being purposely vague to avoid shaming the answerer

I don't think disclosing this information would really be "shaming". On the other hand, it probably isn't worth it to invoke Meta Effect on either your question or the answer, and I think your description of the situation is clear enough to discuss in the abstract.

> Then, when I had actually forgotten about the question, I noticed that someone had answered it. Their answer was the unfortunately common "no sandwich", where they start by saying it's not possible and explain why for a bit, give the answer, and then end with saying it's not possible and that I should do something else. Their middle answer was correct though, and linked to the EXACT file I already used to implement my solution.

There has clearly been a failure to communicate. The person who wrote that answer clearly believes that the middle part does not answer your question, because it would otherwise not be necessary to add those leading and trailing disclaimers. On the other hand, *you* clearly believe that it *does* answer your question, because you considered accepting it.

Please first keep in mind that **resolving the underlying, motivating issue is not the same thing as answering the question**.

First read the answer carefully and try to consider the mindset of the person who wrote it. Why might the author see that "answer" as merely a workaround or otherwise not answering the question as written? Is that issue relevant to the underlying problem? Did you actually intend for the question to depend on the specific thing that was given as a reason why "it's not possible"?

Then consider: **aside from merely *reframing*** the answer from "no, it's not possible, but you can work around it like so:" to "yes, it's possible, by simply doing:" - what would your new answer **substantively *add*** to an understanding of the problem?

If you can add something significant, feel free to [write and even accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), independently of anything else.

However, I would strongly encourage you to do one or more of the following, as appropriate:

- Comment on the existing answer to discuss the situation. (If this requires an extended back-and-forth, you can take it to chat; afterwards, custom-flag one of the comments to say "this entire discussion is No Longer Needed".)
- Edit the question to clarify the exact requirements for **answering the question you want to ask** - which is independent from whether it's exactly what you need to know in order to fix your own code. (Please try to consider the form of the question that would be better for the long-term value of the site.)
- Edit the answer to remove the framing "no"s, if you are confident that the middle part really does answer the question (*especially in this case*, also edit the question so that it's clear that the middle part answers the question). If this is your assessment, then the "no"s are both misleading and [noisy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379), and should be edited out.

Comment: Thanks, I considered all the options and I decided to post my own answer. The best part of the original answer was a link to sample code on github, so I edited it and posted the code inline. I feel like my modifications changed it from "this could help" to "this solves the problem" (and also avoid link rot, as much as is possible for code that references a library which could be deleted at any time).

Comment: I'd suggest against removing framing from someone else's answer -particularly if they're giving context or warnings regarding the associated solution. Otherwise you risk putting words in that user's mouth, i.e.: making it look like they wholly endorse a solution they purposefully cautioned against. If their warnings are factually wrong or misleading, I'd address that in comments or in my own answer, linking to their answer, quoting each point of contest, and dispelling them as necessary.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not satisfied with the other answer, then you should write your own answer that correctly answers your question.

It is [encouraged by Stack Exchange to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions).

> To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.

One of the reasons stated on that blog for writing your own answer:

> - the good information is buried under a sea of bad information.

You have spent a day searching the internet, you found a possible answer which you tested and found to work. This will ultimately help anyone else in the future who has a similar issue.

> Bottom line -- never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site.