# Should I add the [jquery] tag to my post?

Tags: discussion, tags

If I have a problem with a JavaScript routine that also uses jQuery, should I add the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag? The problem doesn't involve the jQuery part.

Pro tag: It is nice for one to know that I am using jQuery. If someone were to modify and test my code, the jQuery part may cause them trouble.

Con tag: The problem is not in the jQuery part.

Comment: "The problem doesn't involve the jquery part." Why not remove the jquery part for the question, then?

Comment: The tags are for what the question is about; if the question isn't about jQuery the the tag isn't relevant. That part of your code is using jQuery is irrelevant. It's a bit like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] because that's the IDE you're wrote the application, or [[tag:windows]] because that's the operating system you aim for the application to run on, but the question is purely about how to achieve a specific task in [[tag:java]].

Comment: Just mention jQuery in the body of the question. As @ThomA said we don't tag questions with VS or Windows, but we may mention those in the question to make sure reproducibility, etc.

Comment: The reason for downvotes is on the tooltip, @dcromley : *"The question does not show research effort; it is not helpful or not useful."* On Meta they can also denote if someone (dis)agrees with the post, but that doesn't seem appropriate here.

Comment: @Thom A  Got it.  Tnx.

Answer (score 11):

The purpose of tags is to categorize **the problem motivating the question**.

People who answer questions on the site, use the tags to find questions that interest them and which pertain to their interests. jQuery specialists would be disappointed to find a question where that skillset isn't relevant to answering. Meanwhile, JavaScript experts who bear some grudge against jQuery could be needlessly turned away from answering a technical question about JavaScript itself.

People who use Stack Overflow to search for existing answers (that's the overwhelming majority of the site's use, and it's [what you should also be doing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking) will want to know what the question is about. While additional inappropriate tags usually won't hurt here, they can be needlessly confusing.

While we're on the topic of searching for answers, keep in mind how the question will look to someone else who happens to have the same fundamental problem. That problem could come up in other contexts, right? In particular, if the problem "is not in the jQuery part" - if you have, as you should, already done the work necessary to *know* that - then "the jQuery part" ought not be **needed to demonstrate** the problem.

We ask for a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for every "what is wrong with the code?" question, because that avoids alienating anyone else who finds the question with a search. Questions here are supposed to be for everyone, not tailored to the person asking, but applicable to anywhere that the same problem occurs.

We [remove "noise"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/) from questions where we can; irrelevant code has the same problem, and removing it allows the site to meet the [objective](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat".

But we can't edit the code as easily - because you're the one who encountered the problem, so it's your responsibility to determine the relevant context. Normally we aren't going to say "oh, obviously this jQuery part isn't relevant to the problem", because a) we haven't done the testing that you've done (are supposed to have done) in order to figure that out; b) simply literally removing those lines of code doesn't necessarily leave a valid example.

Comment: As an addition of what *not* to tag: anything not related to the question. Examples include: the operating system, the code editor, other libraries and frameworks that are not relevant, what technologies the backend is using (when asking for frontend code), what technologies frontend is using (when asking for backend code), [how easy you think the question is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic), and others as long as they don't relate to the question. Just because there is a tag for something which exists in a project somewhere, doesn't make it automatically relevant.