# Shouldn't there be a way to stop sarcastic comments on very low quality questions?

Tags: feature-request, comments, behavior

I've recently came across multiple low quality questions that won't be answered at all, specially those who just write their homework question as it is, even with the grade it has, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450974/creating-the-game-of-word-scramble.

Usually when you see such questions, most of the active users will jump ahead and post either a clarification comment (which in my opinion is constructive and might help the user to understand what is SO for) or a sarcastic comment (which sometimes feels rude and not really needed) to the user.

Shouldn't be there a way to stop all these comments and just keep the ones which clarify to the user what SO is for and directs them to the help center for future reference? In my opinion this might help the community and might encourage new users to actually give it a try and reconstruct his answer after his own trial-and-error.

Comment: You know what would be productive? If we could prevent those _questions_ from appearing in the first place.

Comment: The question is now deleted, but it was a blatant dump of a homework assignment. I sincerely doubt that asker would learn from friendly comments.

Comment: @CodeCaster I doubt there's an ability to prevent those questions from appearing, unless there's a way to detect questions that has "Write a code that..." or "Write a Java/C#/etc... program..." and put them on hold before appearing to others and let a moderator choose if this question is eligible to appear or not, somehow.

Comment: Don't disagree there's an issue here - these questions and the sarcastic comments (which I'm frequently guilty of, too) are absolutely [broken windows.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) There's no way to solve this sanely programmatically, though. For a human-based idea how to tackle this, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336264/a-swat-team-of-nice/336267#336267

Comment: You **flag** sarcastic comments. If we find a pattern of sarcasm by a specific user that is becoming problematic, moderators will have a word with that user. AI is not sufficiently advanced yet for computers to detect such comments, nor do I see a need to automate handling.

Comment: One solution to this would be to add a homework close reason (or sub reason), that way people wouldn't have to waste their time posting "constructive" comments on these questions, they could just close them as homework and the boilerplate close reason would be shown.

Comment: @samgak - We don't need a new close reason for this. Homework question dumps are either "Unclear what you're asking" since they don't ask an actual question or "Too Broad" because any good answer requires doing the whole thing from scratch. Also, the Help Center already has a [boilerplate response](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Shouldn't be there a way to stop all these comments

There already is a way: you can *flag* such comments as non-constructive, and a moderator will delete them. Sarcastic comments are a breach of our [*be nice* policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

When a user receives a series of non-constructive comment flags, there is also an automatic flag indicating that there is a pattern for us moderators to investigate.

There is otherwise no way we can stop the comments from being posted in the first place. AI simply hasn't advanced far enough yet to detect sarcasm reliably.

Comment: you forgot to mention even more efficient way - vote these questions down (along with flagging / voting to close). This feeds automated system that blocks abusive askers (at account and IP level) from polluting the site at all - thus cutting the very root of the problem

Comment: @gnat: sure, but the question asked is if those comments can be stopped. Voting to close and downvoting doesn't do anything to stop the commenting.

Comment: True we don't detect all sarcastic comments, but we have community built [chat bot](https://stackapps.com/questions/7001/heat-detector-analysing-comments-to-find-heat) catching some, with some more work now also together with [perspective](https://www.perspectiveapi.com/), maybe we will catch even more. Note: there is no automatic flagging, flagging is done by users manually.

Comment: you somehow seem to believe in ["rudeness bans"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/165773) that have proven to be inefficient through all the history of the site. "how come that after years of plugging user's mouths and twisting their arms with summers of love and hunting the snark the second top question at MSO is [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601)" The only efficient way to stop such comments is to stop questions causing them. And site has a system capable of that, it only needs more voting down to feed into to work

Comment: @gnat, sure the question is the problem, but I still can't see the use of SO users passing 3,4,5 similar comments *"What have you tried?", "please go back to reading some basic tutorials", "STFW. First result of googling", "This question was generated by a random word generator, right?"* is of any use. We only need to clean up also this cr**p for future users of SO. Just cv and dv, then move on if you have nothing constructive to add.

Comment: @PetterFriberg neither can I but everything that was tried so far didn't work. And it will not work no matter how you try. Even if you find a way to automatically catch and flag _typical_ non-constructive comments - folks angry about flood of homework dumps will simply find more creative ways to express their feelings... which are, frankly, more like a feeling of being powerless in front of garbage dumped at the site - so the real way to handle the issue is to give them more power to clean up

Comment: @gnat Ok, yeah I love cleaning, this is my main job on SO and more power and tools I have the happier I'm. However I still think the idea "bad question"-->"ok to be a bit offensive" just creates more problems and more work for the janitors (users, mods ecc). Lets just state instead "all these frustration comments are of **no use** and should be deleted, please downvote, cv and delete vote instead, keeping to our be-nice policy. *If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does*

Comment: @PetterFriberg that is approach I can agree with, quite a pity that this answer totally ignores the part you describe as "please downvote, cv and delete vote instead" (which makes it frankly rather useless)

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't be there a way to stop all these comments and just keep the one which clarify to the user what SO is for and directs him to the help center for future reference?

As far as I'm concerned, nothing needs to change. We already have a mechanism that tells people to stop commenting and answering, it's called the "close message box", the yellow box shown after putting a question on hold, where the asker can read what they did wrong and how they can fix that.

Before a question is closed, it indeed would be nice to have one comment explaining all the things wrong with the question, and no repetition. But multiple people can say the same things using different words, there's no harm in that.

On the other hand a user who signs up to the site, bypasses all information handed to them during signup, does not read any of the pages that explain how the site works and how to ask a good question, and then continues to copy-paste their homework assignment verbatim into the question box does not deserve time and attention that's better spent at posts that are actually worth it.

If they have no intention in informing themselves how the site works before starting to use it, then we're not going to change that by repeating all the links from the signup and ask a question pages in a friendly comment.

[Also, I don't see any sarcasm here in this screenshot of the now-deleted question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0frGt.png). Sure, there may be less helpful comments, but those are not unique to low-effort questions. You can simply flag them if they are not nice or not constructive, but do note that this flagging happens after the fact, meanwhile the comment stays readable for the OP and other visitors.

So, simply flagging is not an answer to your question.

Comment: You're most likely right and straight to the point, and I just feel that I am more kind than I should be. I didn't mean exactly in this deleted post about the comments, but it's out there in a lot of questions. All what we can do I guess is hoping new users would actually read the information handed to them...

Comment: There absolutely are non-constructive sarcastic comments on that question. I'd have deleted both GhostCat and especially Sanket's remarks if flagged.

Comment: You are also not addressing the question asked; you are basically justifying breaking our be-nice policy because you feel new users that post low-quality crap deserve to receive sarcastic comments. ***Sarcastic comments are non-constructive and can be flagged as such***.

Comment: @Martijn I'm specifically saying I see no sarcasm, so I cannot possibly be saying that it's fine to post sarcastic comments to low-effort questions. Also, flagging does not prevent those comments from being posted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How in the world is ghostcat's comment sarcastic?  It seems *entirely* sincere to me.  It's simply an accurate and straightforward summary of the question; if you find it offensive it would need to be, by nature, because *what the question is, is offensive*.  By saying that merely describing what a help vampire is doing is offensive you're saying that they're more welcome here than people that actually care about quality content.

Comment: @Servy: the quotes around the word question in the whole *what he has tried* line is very sarcastic. There is **no need** for the tone. If you can't say something nice, keep the comments to yourself.

Comment: @Servy: and I don't appreciate your 'if you are not allowing such comments you must be welcoming the help vampires' vibe either. We have plenty of tools to deal with the content. Vote down, vote to close, once closed, feel free to vote to delete.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The question *didn't actually ask a question*, making it not actually a question (despite being posted as one), hence the quotes.  Again, that comment *isn't inappropriate*.  There's nothing about it that's not nice.  It's terse.  It's stating facts, rather than embellishing (positively or negatively).  That's not wrong.

Comment: @Servy: I see it as non-constructive and talking to the peanut gallery. It did not need posting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And I don't appreciate your, "you're not allowed to politely tell other people when they do something wrong" statements.  Deleting comments that *appropriately* inform people when they do something wrong, out of fear of offending the help vampires at being told that they did something wrong, and forcing people to only ever interact with such questions silently (knowing full well that those tools are woefully insufficient to handle the problem) is *going* to discourage those users, all so that you can have more help vampires using the site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I'm aware you see it as not constructive, as you've said as much. I'm saying that that's wrong, and it's not inappropriate at all, and it's sending the message that SE doesn't care about quality content and that you *want* questions like these when you remove content like that.

Comment: @Servy: Are we even talking about the same comment here? The comment was addressed to Riaan, not the poster.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I'm aware that the comment used the reply function to Riaan.  And in doing so, it was pointing out what the question did wrong, something that the OP would likely find useful information (if they cared) or anyone else who's interested in knowing what's wrong with the question (if they're new here and didn't know).  It's a comment, not a PM.