# Edit past personal posts badge for fun empathy and profit

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I sorted [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2909897/mbigras?tab=questions&sort=newest) by "newest" and then went to the last page. These questions are from years ago when I was just learning about SO. I was amazed at how poor the quality was.

Going through my own queue was fun, nostalgic, and humbling. I was able to improve the markdown format, [remove fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/2909897), and clarify questions.

This was an especially interesting experience because I've recently started helping with [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review). I think practicing patience and empathy with my past self was easier than with others but the skills will definitely cross over.

Overall, the experience was fun and helpful for me and also the community because my past questions are formatted better and I'll be more skilled in the [Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

This got me thinking that others could benefit from a similar experience. There are [many badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188731) that involve editing or answering questions when time has passed. However, these explicitly leave out personal posts.

I'd like to suggest a discussion about badges for edits on very old personal posts, on the order of 1, 2, or 3 years. I think after that time several things will likely be true about users who are still around:

- they're probably fairly dedicated to participating in the community
- they've probably learned more about code, how to ask/format a good question, and how to participate successfully with the community
- they rarely think about questions from 1-3 years ago
- they are participating in various moderation duties

I think having the badges would help users to:

- improve their own questions
- improve their editing skills
- improve their empathy for newcomers
- have fun by looking at their past selves on SO

Would love to hear thoughts/discussion about questions like:

- Have you tried looking at your old questions?
- What was it like?
- Did you benefit?
- Would SO benefit from past personal question badges?

Comment: The introduction of a badge would bump billions of ropey old questions to visibility, as literally quite a few users will just do anything for a badge. Improving old questions (or answers) seems a good idea, but not everyone will be as thoughtful as you are about it and there is the visibility issue (which gives new questions less visibility).

Comment: Interesting idea. Some rep-gain requirement may help quality of edits like "own question gained 3+ upvotes after editing at least 2 years later"