# Where has all the community gone?

Tags: discussion

I haven't been here from day 1, but I've been here a damned long time at this point.  Stack Overflow has been one of my favorite places on the web for nearly a decade.

Back then (grumbles the old guy in the corner) we talked about the way things were like we were people, we had discussions, we were brothers and sisters in this digital life.  A little comment here and there, a little humor at no ones expense but maybe our own was part of that conversation.

Now we still have these brilliant people zipping around answering questions which is amazing as always... but we have this... undercurrent, this obsession of some users with trimming questions they didn't write... not for accuracy or clarity... but because they have personality.  Or they have opinions other people disagree with.

Moreover, there is no defense against it.  The a gentleman recently gutted one of my posts, then gutted again after I attempted to correct. Then admonished me for having a personality. Then flagged my comment when I pointed out he was being petty.

Look... there are already textbooks out there.  I can go read them, but I don't want to, I learn better interacting with humans who have style and humor and who I can connect with.

I don't get why "we" (the people of SO) are doing it.  I don't get the point of sucking the life out of Stack Overflow.

> How do I get Blargotron to loop through members of a structure

vs

> OMG Blargotron is giving me fits, can someone please help me understand how to get the damned thing to loop through a structure.

The question remains clear, but the passion is a little more obvious.  Is there anything REALLY wrong with that?

Is it a requirement to be dull? Is it the intended course of the site that it read like a phonebook?  Is there a course of action to encourage people to just leave it alone?

==============

The edited version to save anyone time who might wish to rewrite my question:

Recent experiences have raised the question to if editing user queries to be devoid of any style or personality is the intended purpose of Stack Overflow, and what might be done to quell such behaviour if it is not the intended course of action.

Comment: Your account has existed for most of SO's history, but you haven't exactly been much of a contributor throughout that time.  It doesn't seem like you really have the experience to really have judged the personality of SO's content, either in the past, or now, as you haven't been an active part of it.

Comment: How is how often I've contributed in any way equivalent to how many answers and discussions I've read? Exactly?

Comment: I've been here since... day 10 or so? And what you're describing has been a part of the site since pretty much the start; the software encourages it. If anything, discussion became a lot more common and a lot more... Social... over time, as first comments were introduced and then inbox notifications for said comments.

Comment: @gnat:  I agree with the dupe but I feel like this is its own question anyway.  This is a person trying to reconcile what is a long time of policy and changes, and I don't feel like that dupe does enough to explain it.

Comment: Fair enough Shog9.  I looked back through my old questions... it didn't happen to me then, only recently. I'll accept that this isn't new I guess.  Lame, but it is what it is...

Comment: @OhkaBaka You're talking about a contribution that you've made that has created some friction as a result of your misunderstanding of community expectations, and you have therefore assumed that the community's expectations have changed radically over time.  In reality, the community's expectations *haven't* changed (at least in this one respect) over time.  Had you contributed in the way you did in your recent post more regularly in the past, you'd have had the same reaction.  Watching a community doesn't help you understand it's expectations quite as much as being an active participant.

Comment: @OhkaBaka The fact that you only experienced this personally isn't a result of the community's values changing.  Everyone is telling you that the community's values *haven't* been changing in this way.  You haven't experienced this before because you haven't been posting that type of content before.  Had you done so earlier, you most likely would have experienced a similar reaction earlier.

Comment: Textual broadcast communication is inherently unpredictable; you can follow the same template 100 times and get 100 different responses based who happens to read it and how they interpret it. As frustrating as that can be, it's also a great opportunity: you can get answers to problems that no one you've previously interacted with could hope to solve.

Comment: _"Where has all the community gone?"_ Slowly torn apart by the crushing tidal masses [of the eternal September](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56817/).

Comment: I respect all of these comments. Well maybe not @GEOCHET, but otherwise... Very well said all.

I still think asking someone to tone down their snark is billion times more dignified and professional than deleting it yourself... but yeah, I can own that I brought a gallon of snark-sauce to the party.

Comment: @OhkaBaka That's yet another example of community norms and expectations on SO.  On SO when there is a problem with the presentation of a post, the accepted course of action is to just fix it.  Telling someone else to fix a problem that you can just fix yourself is a lot more work for everyone involved (you to explain a fix, them to understand it, the time of everyone reading the comment, etc.).  On SO telling someone else that there's a problem you could just as easily fix yourself is considered the less appropriate course of action.

Comment: Seems inherently trolly, but I acquiesce to the wisdom of the community.

Comment: @OhkaBaka trolly? to go in and edit your post, making it clearer for future visitors? That feels helpful, not trolly at all. And if you think we can't have fun or have personality in our posts... you haven't seen Zalgo, have you?

Comment: @Patrice I'm all about clearer... in my passion originally I f-bombed this very post and didn't realize it... having that... cleaned up wouldn't bother me either... what is this Zalgo you speak of?

Comment: @OhkaBaka Just use your favourite search engine to look up how to parse HTML with regex.

Answer (score 16):

You can have personality in your posts.  Lost of people embellish their posts, add some humor here and there, and truly have their own voice in their posts.  This has always been acceptable, and it's still acceptable now.

But that personality has limits, because this is [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).  This doesn't mean you can't have fun, but you do need to be rather careful with when and how you use it.  The fun needs to not distract from the post(s) they are a part of, and ideally contribute positively towards it.  Humor that's both sparsely used and well integrated with the points being made can greatly improve understanding from readers by making the post more engaging, but just tacking on jokes or tangents into the post when they don't help add to the point being made is often distracting, making it harmful, and will be responded to accordingly.

Tone also matters a lot.  SO is a site for *professionals*.  While humor, when used appropriately, is certainly acceptable, that humor needs to be the type of humor that's acceptable in a professional context, so, for example, including expletives, as you did in your example, isn't going to be the type of personality that would be acceptable to include in a post.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  I believe the most offensive comment I made in my last post was how "Observables" are horribly named and I wanted to petition to call them "Blackholables" ...

Comment: @OhkaBaka I'm not sure where f-word is considered professional, but SO is  definitely not not such a place. While you are entitled for your own opinion adding it to a post (as a full word or acronym) is likely to be edited out (and potentially flagged as "rude or offensive").

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov heh... quite right sir... I didn't realize I f-bombed that post... and wouldn't have been upset if that had been the limit of the edit. (edit: OH... THIS post... I didn't even see that... apologies, bad form... corrected)

Answer (score 10):

If you're having a problem, I need as much information **about the problem** as possible to help you solve it.  Whether or not Blargotron has given you fits to the point that you caught yourself baking a cake with the name of FooModule just so you could hurl it at a wall is *irrelevant* to the actual problem[s] you have.

A lot has changed in nine or so years.

Comment: I appreciate that... I'm not saying not providing info is good, but saying "I have trouble grokking Blargotron" is not INHERENTLY detrimental... If ALL I talk about is how much I hate it, obviously it impairs your ability to answer, but that is different.

Comment: Additionally, is the idea that you can just go and change someone else's narrative ok with the community at large?

Comment: @OhkaBaka:  There is a fine line between explaining the problem and noise.  Saying "I don't understand Blargotron" is implied given that you're asking a question about it.  Specifying *what* you don't understand about Blargotron is more valuable since it eliminates ambiguity and cross-chatter.

Comment: @OhkaBaka:  For your second question, check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/1079354