# How do you reply to someone who has edited your question?

Tags: support, edits, comment-replies

How do you reply to someone who has edited your question? Or is this purposely not allowed?

Comment: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). Basically, the way you did it: pinging them in a comment.

Comment: For the record, IMO removing the mysql tag from that question was perfectly fine. Your question is not about mysql, but about mysql-workbench.

Comment: @yivi If pedantry is important to you then please make sure to remove the mysql tag from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008305/how-to-modifie-the-standard-path-of-mysql-workbench-which-points-to-where-backup also. If pedantry is not important to you please either return the mysql tag or explain the real reason the mysql tag was removed.  Also, removing "Any help would be much appreciated" has achieved nothing except make me want to stop contributing to this site.

Comment: Maybe you should also read this post: [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Comment: Please, do not take all this personally. These edits are not meant as attacks on you or your post, but are made by other users like yourself working on improving the site's content.

Comment: pedantry should be important to all of us. It sets this site apart from the cruft found in *forums*.

Comment: @yivi Thank you for the answer and at least being consistent. I read the 'fluff' question and answers and I'm going to continue thanking people and showing my appreciation. Go ahead and delete all the 'appreciated' and 'thank you' lines from my questions and answers if it suits you (including this one). I recommend you read this post first though -
 https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d.

Comment: Believe it or not, it is not the first time someone brings up this particular article in meta. Suit yourself.

Comment: @JamesJones Why so agitated over something that unimportant? Why so reluctant to adapt to such a minor aspect of site culture?

Comment: @ModusTollens - "Why so agitated over something that unimportant?" I could ask the same of all of you. There is a *firehose* of awful low effort questions pouring in every second but you all care more about 6 words expressing gratitude. *That* is what agitates me. "Why so reluctant" - I don't chitchat on SO except to use basic manners. I understand the value of getting to the point. I'm not writing out my life story here..... I think I'll stick to answering questions from now on. Asking a question on this site is like something out of one of Kafka's essays.

Comment: Are we still using that blog post from 2015 to convince us we're awful at what we're doing? You would expect more/newer evidence would have surfaced by now...

Comment: @JamesJones Just for the record: I comment _a lot_ on that firehose of low effort questions to make them better, only to have that effort sabotaged more and more often by high rep users who answer that crap, therebye removing all incentive for OP to make it better. I am not agitated, but I am fed up by long term users who actively work against enforcing the guidelines. Knowingly keeping salutations is just part of that. Why not try to change the site via a feature request or a discussion?

Comment: 'there is a bigger problem here'. Sure. Doesn't mean we shouldn't clear low hanging fruits though....  And the post you link has no bearing to removing thanks from posts.... So not sure why it resurfaces here.

Comment: @ModusTollens - "Why not try to change the site via a feature request or a discussion?" am I not doing that right now? After your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523396/interpolate-function-using-apache-commons-math/36523685#36523685 you are thanked a few times. My condolences, that must have really ruined your day. There you commented "hope this helps" which is about as fluffy as "Any help would be much appreciated". That was 2016 though, maybe you regret that I don't know.

Comment: @JamesJones I wrote that in a comment, not the answer. That's ok. When we talk about salutations to be removed we are talking about them in questions and answers. You are a swell person, by the way. /s Good luck for your future, I am out.

Comment: @ModusTollens - you don't need to be patronising because you have an arbitrary distinction on what constitutes fluff to make your fluff okay. Or maybe you really do think I'm a swell person :)

Comment: @JamesJones it is not an arbitrary distinction. It is a distinction you seem to be unaware of.

Comment: @yivi - Well of course I was unaware of it. He only made it up 5 minutes ago.

Comment: @JamesJones that's patently false. You should inform yourself before spouting nonsense.

Comment: Comments are treated unlike posts here. Stuff that would never ever fly in answers or questions are normal In comments... It's easy to think that the distinction is arbitrary, if you assume malice from everyone. Take a second, look it up, assume other users commenting here are genuine. It should go muuuuuch smoother.

Comment: @yivi - I searched and can't find the authoritative source that says "thank you" in the comments is okay but a phrase like "any help would be much appreciated" in a question is not okay. The closest thing I could find is some opinions in a comment chain in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions you linked me to. But the opposite opinion is upvoted too. So I continue to conclude ModusTollens made up a definition of fluff on the spot to suit him. If you can link me to the authoritative source that proves me wrong I'll happily admit it.

Comment: Users were courteous and tried to educate you, but chose to ignore anyone and keep flinging absurd accusations. You are starting to behave like a troll. So I am very sorry to say that I'm going to treat you as one and ignore you. Before I go, the gist you should be aware of: **fluff in posts should be edited out, fluff-only comments should be flagged as "no longer needed", some fluff included in an otherwise useful comment can be left alone**. Have a good day.

Comment: @Patrice - I don't assume malice from anyone here. This is just a debate right? I assume everyone here are generally good people, judging by their SO scores. What should go muuuuuuuch smoother? I did look it up and couldn't find it so a link would be appreciated. Oops "scratch would be appreciated"

Comment: @JamesJones The reason why fluff in questions and answers is removed is because SO is supposed to work like a list of FAQs with answers. FAQs traditionally contain facts, they are not like entries in a forum or a discussion. That's why they should look more like that. I've never seen FAQs containing salutations or fluff in the wild. (Just for further information. A lot of guidelines have a background, you are invited to do some research.)

Comment: @yivi - So I clicked a few of your questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804369/wordpress-datepicker-works-on-widgets-options-page-but-not-on-customizer has "thanks and regards", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875348/capture-end-of-line-string-but-avoid-capturing-matching-trailing-characters has a smiley, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684801/styling-nested-unordered-list-into-columns has "Any takers?", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657638/add-post-hook-to-a-bitbucket-repository-using-their-rest-api-and-python-requests has "Thanks in advance and regards". Fluff

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My mistake. Feel free to edit them out, of course. And please stop talking to me.

Comment: @yivi - I've got better things to do. So do you. That's what I've been arguing the whole time. But if I did care about fluff phrases I'd damn well make sure my own house is in order before editing other people's posts.

Comment: Ridiculous, silly and misguided as most of your arguments are; you do have a point. Just went through and fixed all my old questions I could find. I even flagged a couple for closure! Thanks a lot. Something good came out of your trolling in the end.

Comment: @yivi - Come on man, I'm not a troll. Give me some credit, my rep's just a little lower than yours. We just happen to disagree on something. I just came to meta to ask how to reply to an edit - you started the argument. My only sin is being happy to engage. Anytime you want to provide that authoritative link would be great by the way. Don't worry, this will be the last thread I ever start on meta. This place is like the fun police.

Comment: Not assuming malice? The second someone disagrees with you you link to an old, mostly unrelated thread saying stack is full of trolls. Then when given an explanation you assume that person made it up. If you don't want people to think you're a troll.... Stop behaving like one,maybe? And what would go much smoother is your overall interactions on this site. Also... When someone says fluff is fine in comments, spare us the passive agressiveness about fluff in comments... It doesn't help your 'I am not a troll'argument. With that, I think I'll join yivi and stop this pointless discussion

Comment: @Patrice My overall interactions on this site are smooth as silk 99% of the time. Using fluff like 'thanks', 'much appreciated' etc helps with that. I don't use meta much and had no idea everyone here has PTSD from that article. I would have used something else if I knew. I found it through the relatively recent thread at https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/54f62f/the_decline_of_stack_overflow/. I'm just making points to try and win the argument. Just for the record my argument is simple phrases like 'thank you', 'much appreciated' or the ':)' you use in some answers is not a problem

Comment: @JamesJones I think your question is a dupe, but I can't see an acceptable reason behind the downs. Unfortunately, the meta sites have this sad side-effect. Don't worry on it - if you know that your post is good, there is no reason to delete it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), you can ping in comments any user who has edited a post:

> #### Who can be notified with this feature?
>
> - The author of the post.
>
>   Note that the author of the post will *always* be notified of any
>   new comment. You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if
>   only you and the author have commented on the post so far, the *@name*
>   will be [automatically
>   removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099)
>   from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.
> - Any user who has a visible (non-deleted) comment on the post.
>
>   Note that if a user comments on their own post and there is only one
>   other person who has previously commented on that post, then that
>   person is [also
>   notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts),
>   even if *@name* is not used.
> - Any user who has edited the post (does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions).
> - For questions: The moderator or gold badge holder who closed or reopened the question. Users who have closed or reopened a question
>   *without* a binding close vote (i.e. without a gold tag badge or a moderator vote) cannot be notified.
> - For questions: any user who set a bounty on the question (current or expired)

So what you did was sufficient to contact the editor (who as far as I can see, apparently already saw your message)