# How can I get further feedback as to why a question has been closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I have asked a [Go programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65907011/how-to-convert-date-to-rfc3339-extended-date-string-with-milliseconds-in-go) on the Go programming Stack Overflow community, which has recently been closed.

Initially, I received feedback in the close link for the question, i.e. it is not reproducible or was caused by typos. No further specific comments were issued, other than in the timeline:

> Not suitable for this site

The question was a Go programming question. Which site should I have asked the question on?

I since solved the problem highlighted in my question and [posted reproducible code](https://play.golang.org/p/ChSZyv70KE7) that highlights the issue and a solution. Later this evening I will be eligible for accepting my own answer, but I am not sure if I can do this if the question is closed. The question was then closed with the same generic reason and no additional comments or reasons. It was closed stating that the question is not reproducible or was caused by typos.

The problem was not caused by a typo, i.e. I am trying to learn the Go programming language and asked a question to the Stack Overflow Go programming community with respect on how to convert a timestamp stored in a [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database into an RFC3339 formatted date. Furthermore, I made edits to produce [reproducible code](https://play.golang.org/p/ChSZyv70KE7). No comment was made stating why the person that closed the question believed it was caused by a typo or was not reproducible.

[This link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) suggests:

> Asking in the meta site allows those who took the action to comment, and will help others to learn about the issues being discussed.

Also, I am curious as to why my answer was edited to remove the comment:

> Hope this solution helps other new golang developers!

How do I find out further information/feedback concerning why this question was closed to enable me to determine if this was done fairly?

Comment: For the generic case, you can @-ping [the close voters](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65907011/timeline). For this specific case, the [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65907011/1) of the question is quite short and looks like it might be trivial or unclear, and seeing close votes for those sorts of questions is pretty common (though I don't know anything about Go).

Comment: For the last part: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: As @CertainPerformance mentioned - its first revision(s) were a little lacking but your latest revision looks reasonable to me - it's been re-opened.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Actually, you can only @ ping users who acted unilaterally on the post, e.g. hammered it, edited it, etc. Of course, you can also ping users who commented on the post.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. To ping do I just @<username> the close voters in comments?

Comment: You can only @ping users if they were the only close voter (diamond mod or gold badge dupehammer)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I cannot speak for the close voters as I was not one, but my hypothesis follows:

Your question, in its original form, was fine. It was short, sweet, and to the point. It included information about what you'd tried and the error it produced. Not a fantastic question by any means, but far better than most posted by new users.

Then... [you started editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65907011/revisions). Adding some more detail. Which is fine! But then... you kept editing it. And kept editing it. Adding info that's irrelevant and most crucially, changing the title to ask a completely **different** question to the original one.

That's a no-no: questions on Stack Overflow **are not** expected to change materially after they are asked, because doing so is likely to invalidate any answers already posted there. If you discover that your original question was asking the wrong thing, you should rather post a new question, linking back to the old question with a short explanation so that people don't think you're reposting the same question to get attention.

And then you *kept on editing* the question, adding more and more detail (some of it again irrelevant), and some users viewing it got alarmed that it kept changing because again, that could invalidate any answers, and so they voted to close it to calm you down, presumably with the intent that once you've finished your edit spree, they'd return to reopen it.

Stack Overflow should be the **last** place you ask a question. It's evident to me from the revision history that after you asked that question, you continued to investigate and search and figure out the issue, **and that's great** - if we had more users who were actually willing to look further than the end of their noses, the site as a whole would be in a much better place.

But Stack Overflow isn't a place for recording your actions while you're performing an investigation. It's a place where you post a question **after** you've exhausted all available avenues of that investigation. (You can also post a question and answer it yourself, if you've performed an investigation that succeeded with an outcome that you feel would be useful to future users.)

And a question is effectively expected to be immutable. It should contain all the research you've done, all the information to provide context, and a clear description of the problem to tie those pieces together. If you have to substantially modify a question after you've asked it, you've either asked it too early or you've asked the wrong thing.

Further, questions should **not** contain irrelevant information, such as "thanks" or "I'm a new user" or "I asked this question elsewhere" or "hope this helps". That information does not contribute to answering the question, which means it should be left out (and in this case, [is why it was edited out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)).

In future, keep your research progress steps in a text file on your desktop, and use them to write a full and detailed question once you're sure you either have a workable solution, or face a problem that others might be able to help with.

Please understand, that Stack Overflow gets literally *thousands* of new questions every day. Practically that means that in order for any question you ask to have a chance of getting an answer (never mind a good answer), that question needs to stand out from the crowd. And the best way to make a question stand out is to ask one that's full, complete, and answerable.

Conversely, probably the worst way to go about asking is to post a question that lacks enough detail to be answered, because such a question is likely to be ignored at best and closed at worst - both paths are generally a death knell for any question, regardless of how good it may be at its core, or may eventually become through editing. So help yourself by writing a good question from the outset, and you'll find your time on Stack Overflow to be far more rewarding.

Comment: Ok, thanks, yes added edits to question. In future, could I append information to the question, sort of like updating things I have tried to solve?

Comment: @anon_dcs3spp yes, but don't ignore what the second half of the answer tells you. You shouldn't have to add a long list of things you tried after the fact, you should have already tried them before asking in the first place. That is in your own benefit the most, because the better a question looks the first moment it is posted, the better it will look to people when the question is first seen by them. If it makes a bad first impression, it is hard to recover from that even with the most vigorous spit polish.

Comment: Ok thanks all for the feedback. Will adhere to this when asking future questions

Comment: Just as an FYI, mods get an autoflag if you edit too many times. Most often it's old canonicals, but if a new question ever hits that threshold it's usually a sign of the problems Ian outlined.