# How to handle superfluous claims in answers

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

When someone makes a statement in an answer like "this is the most optimal solution" should this be [removed as fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)?

Taken literally, it is a claim about the performance or readability of the solution provided in the answer. When unsupported, I feel this claim should be challenged but know it's probably just a superfluous remark. It sounds arrogant to me, but I also understand that people from different cultures are likely to read into this kind of statement differently, and I don't wish to get into edit wars or comment flaming over a misunderstanding.

I have, in this instance, flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: The flag will probably be declined. That's not something requiring mod intervention. You could have suggested an edit, but it may well have been rejected by the author.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is fluff/noise, no. Many of the users here are very well versed experts in their subjects, so may well be able to make such a claim. If you want to user to cite why it might be the most performant, add a comment asking them to do so. If you know it isn't performant, then you could comment why, or downvote and move on.

Comment: Every time I've seen that statement, I find it's absolutely *not* the optimal solution at all. To me it just read the same as a `<bling>`-tag or an `h1`-header. Some times I'll compare the results of the Answers just to check up on my own bias. I'll usually post my findings as a comment on the post ;)

Comment: The problem with absolute claims is they're almost always [the only text in the post and/or have no rationale provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372104/best-practice-for-defining-button-events-in-android/9989693#9989693), and usually accompany bad-to-mediocre solutions. However, these statements are not a superfluous greeting or self-promotion of a third-party tool, and removing it seems inappropriate unless it's a community wiki post. I usually add a comment asking "what makes this the best approach, exactly?" and downvote if it's also a poor solution (usually the case).

Comment: @Larnu Would it make any difference to you if it was a new user or someone with a high reputation? It's possible that an experienced developer could be new to SO but this doesn't seem to be the usual case.

Comment: There are a *few* users that I trust in my area of expertise, @Andy2K11, but I've likely read the material they have published that backs up said claim. But there is at least 1 individual in the tags I am a (self proclaimed) expert in that has **significantly** more reputation than I do and I have questioned their claims/methods several times. TL;DR: For me [so] reputation has nothing to do with it, industry reputation does.

Comment: I'm not sure you mean "superfluous" there. The information you describe is neither *excessive*, nor *unnecessary*. Both of these are qualities of superfluous. The statement you mention might indeed be very relevant. Your point of contention seems to be that it's *unverifiable* or perhaps even *wrong*.

Comment: In nearly all cases, I find that "_most optimal solution_" is an _opinion_ as opposed to a statement of fact.  Even best practise is simply an opinion (albeit of experts).  I tend to treat these statement as the subjective terms that they typically are

Comment: Sometimes it's a fact claim, other times opinion, but sometimes just a phrase like "this is an awesome answer for you". It might appear to be the later, but as it's been pointed out, it might be that there is a generally accepted *standard* optimal solution which domain experts would all recognise without explanation and I as a domain noob didn't know. I would consider "awesome" to be superfluous in most cases, but "optimal" adds a degree of ambiguity.

Comment: (1) "this is the most optimal solution" --> (2) "this is _probably_ the most optimal solution" --> (3) "this is the most optimal solution, IMO" Here (2)/(3) are just expressing an opinion. But, (1) can also be viewed as expressing an opinion. And, the author [or others] may offer several possible solutions, and then (1) becomes even _less_ "egregious", because of context.

Comment: @CraigEstey This may well be a quite good if not optimal solution, at the very least a solution if it is one and in case it's the only one then definitely also the optimal one, I think, perhaps (who knows really).

Comment: @Trilarion Everything one posts _is_ just an opinion. Except that one [of course]. Ironic, no?

Comment: @CraigEstey I wonder how much information is contained in such opinions. What is the value of "Maybe this is the optimal solution", which an opinion comes down to?

Comment: In a textbook, that might often be followed by "the proof of which is left as an exercise for the reader."

Answer (score 29):

Ask for clarification in the comments, then edit the post based on the response.

Optimization is a tricky thing, as the fastest solution depends on the dataset that's being tested, and the specific software and hardware versions involved. But even "I didn't try the other solutions because this could handle half a million entries in a second" is valuable.

Or maybe the author really meant "easiest solution". Developer speed is important too!

---

Note: Moderators don't (can't!) typically check answers for factual accuracy. I suspect the moderator will do nothing, or take an action that you could have taken yourself (e.g. commenting). The flag may or may not be declined for this reason.  Only an expert can check if an answer is any good. Feel free to point out the problems with an answer in the comments too, and perhaps vote appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Edits should not conflict with the author's intent, even when what the author intended to say is something you believe to be wrong, likely to be wrong, or at least unsupported.

A statement that a solution is optimal is not fluff. If the solution is optimal, then it is useful information; if the solution is not optimal, then it is misinformation. The way to handle answers which are useful is to upvote them, the way to handle answers which are incorrect is to downvote them. The principle here is that you should use votes, not edits, to address the factual accuracy and usefulness of an answer according to the author's intent. (You should still edit to fix factual errors caused by typos or other clearly unintentional mistakes.)

If you believe that a claimed-optimal solution is not optimal, then you may consider also leaving a comment explaining why that is; your comment may prompt the original author to edit their answer, or otherwise can at least be useful to other readers. If you are not sure whether the solution is optimal or not, then you may consider leaving a comment asking the author to explain why they say so.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I would just insert "I think that" before "this is" and making the statement a) more true and b) correcting the importance of the statement. Without any further backup it's just an opinion and should be treated as such (unless it's an obvious statement).

Removing it completely may not be the best idea because the voters may already have validated the statement with their upvotes. They may know that it's true and removing the statement may remove information from the answer.

Of course it immediately begs the question "Why do you think that this is the most optimal solution?" and that should be asked as a comment for sure (as [Laurel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412592/1536976) already pointed out).

Comment: When I see unreferenced statements like that, I automatically assume it's the author's opinion. Explicitly marking it as such is just unnecessary hedging: the meaning doesn't change at all.

Comment: @Laurel For you it might mean the same, for others it might be different. One could also assume that somebody who writes a confident statement like this knows more and just forgot to mention the reasons. Explicitly marking as an opinion would clarify the situation in my eyes.

Comment: Given the Q&A nature of SO I would lean towards removing ambiguity. A statement such as "This is the most optimal solution I've found" would at least give some indication as to what the opinion was based on so you could make your own judgement. That, of course, would require input from the OP.

Comment: Upvotes don't necessarily mean upvoters are endorsing the sentiment behind the "this is optimal" statement; they might have just found the code useful. I don't think many take these statements literally, which is why they're probably fluff, but fluff that's hard to remove nonetheless because it's hard to definitively infer that OP's intent was "I think...". They really may believe it to be objectively the best.

Comment: @ggorlen Sure, but maybe it also means that they agree with the statement. Would you rather simply remove it?

Comment: I'd rather just leave my vote, if I disagree with their assertion that the solution is "the best".

Comment: I'd love to remove them, along with a lot of other baseless statements often made in answers, but I feel that it's overreach for non-community wiki answers, where edits should strive to preserve OP's intent foremost. I downvote, take it with a grain of salt, and/or add a comment prompting for an explanation, and hope people will (someday) elevate the rigor of their answers (not gonna happen). In contrast, answers that say "Hi. How are you today?" or "Hope this helps -John" are fine to edit out because this is pure fluff that adds nothing to the content of the answer.

Comment: @ggorlen "I mostly downvote..." So in case that not many people did the same and there are lots of upvotes instead it may mean that people voted the statement true filling it with meaning.

Comment: Well, they're certainly entitled to do that.

Comment: It's almost as if the system was designed for that purpose

Comment: @KevinB in principle you can claim anything in an answer. The validity of that is determined by the score. It gets tricky if more than one distinct answer claims to be the optimal solution. The alternative would be that we require that all statements made anywhere must be backed up properly. There might not be much left, but it might be solid as a rock.

Comment: The validity of a post isn't determined by the score, it's determined by you. If someone posts something that's false, and it's upvoted, it doesn't change the fact that it's false. There's no way to require all statements made anywhere to be backed up properly. What does "properly" even entail? I'm not sure what your expectations are here...

Comment: @ggorlen "The validity ..[is] determined by you." Not if I'm the consumer of knowledge. Then I have to trust what is being produced by the content creators, who are the experts and I'm the learner. So if a 1million rep user writes that something is the optimal solution, I would probably have to believe him. And since we cannot realistically require that people back up their statements in any way, the only gauge measure we have is the score. Answers can be wrong and parts of answers can be wrong. I would really take the score as a measure of the truth value of the statements in an answer.

Comment: I don't follow. You don't **have** to believe anything! Human history is rife with "experts" saying something, everyone backing them up, and it turns out they're totally wrong. Of course, genuine experts are usually right, but they don't usally make absolute claims. Again, I'm not sure what you're proposing here exactly. You're suggesting if someone makes a false or hyperbolic statement and gets hundreds of upvotes, that we should edit the post to be truthful? Then, you have one person uniliterally imposing their version of the truth on the post, which is not OK. Just downvote if you disagree.

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry for any misunderstanding. I was digressing a lot with the last comments. I would like to explain the things I was thinking about better to you, but I feel this is not the right format for that here. That's why I just limit myself to this answer. I think that marking unbacked statements as personal opinions and asking in a comment for the "why" of the statement (and voting of course too) is all that should be done.